# How to recover the deleted partition and get its UUID in macOS

Tags: macos, partition

My MacBook Air has installed Ubuntu, and I want to remove it and expand the Mac partition, so I delete the original partitions, like this picture:

[image]

but I forget to note the UUID of disk0s2 and disk0s3, so when I make Partition, there is a problem, like that:

[image]

So how can I recover the partition ?

Comment: Any reason you did not use the MacOS Disk utility for this?

Answer (score 3):

You have to destroy the GUID partition table and create a new one. The UUIDs of the various partition types are fixed. You can get some or most of them here: [Partition type GUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs).

Below I assume that your MacBook Air contains an SSD and the main partition was formatted as CoreStorage volume. You can check this in Recovery Mode with a method outlined here: [OS volume shows as type 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFF' (last part)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/305712/93229)

**Preparation:**

- Detach any external drive (especially your external Time Machine backup drive)
- Restart to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup.

  The prerequisites are the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot into a recovery netboot image which usually is loaded from an Apple/Akamai server.

  I recommend ethernet because it's more reliable. If you are restricted to WIFI and the boot process fails, just restart your Mac until you succeed booting.
  You can either use `fdisk` or `gpt` to remove the MBR at block 0. If you use an admin user prepend `sudo` using the `gpt ....` commands.
- First get an overview. This step is important before you destroy the gpt, because it's the source to rebuild it from scratch:

  ```
  gpt -r show /dev/disk0
  ```
- Then delete the gpt:

  ```
  diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0
  gpt destroy /dev/disk0
  ```
- Create a new GUID partition table:

  ```
  gpt create -f /dev/disk0
  ```
- Finally add all common Mac partitions one by one based on details shown in the `gpt -r show /dev/disk0` output:

  ```
  gpt add -b 40 -s 409600 -i 1 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B /dev/disk0
  gpt add -b 134167720 -s 1269760 -i 3 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
  gpt add -b 409640 -s 133758080 -i 2 -t 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
  ```

  *Hint*: You may add and remove partitions in an arbitrary order if you keep the right index number. In the above commands I added the third partition (`... -i 3 ...`) before adding the second partition (`... -i 2 ...`). You don't have to unmount disk0 then because the partitions i=1 and i=3 don't contain auto-mounted volumes while the second partition does.
- Check the disk with `diskutil verifyDisk disk0`
- Check the disk with `diskutil verifyVolume disk0s2`

---

**Resizing the main volume to fill the whole disk**

Finally you want to resize the main volume to fill the whole disk.

- Get an overview with:

  ```
  diskutil cs list
  ```

  You may have several CoreStorage Logical Volume Groups, if you boot from an external drive with a full system! Use the proper one!
- Resize the whole stack:

  ```
  diskutil cs resizeStack lvUUID size #lvUUID is the UUID of the Logical Volume. Usually it's the last one listed.
  ```

  Booted to Yosemite you can use `0g` for the size to expand it. 0g is a "magical" size here.

  ```
  diskutil cs resizeStack lvUUID 0g
  ```

  Booted to El Capitan or later you have to use a real size like `120g`. If you get an error use a slightly smaller size like `119g` or`199500m`.

  ```
  diskutil cs resizeStack lvUUID 120g
  ```

Comment: Danke!  Klanomath, Ich habe geschafft 1