# Unable to find an APFS Container Reference after fixing FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF error

Tags: macos, disk-utility, high-sierra, apfs, diskutil

After following this [guide](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff) and giving my partition the proper GUID, i can't access it.

Is there a way to recover the container reference its supposed to have or at least a way for me to extract data from it?

```
$diskutil list

/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS                         209.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         41.6 GB    disk0s3
```

disk0s2 is the one i "fixed"

```
$diskutil verifyVolume disk0s2

Started file system verification on disk0s2
Error: -69564: Unable to find an APFS Container Reference
```

.

```
diskutil apfs list
APFS Container (1 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 0745562A-15FE-40A4-B07F-54F4AE6FC742
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk1
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      41572282368 B (41.6 GB)
    Minimum Size:                 18695892992 B (18.7 GB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   18028277760 B (18.0 GB) (43.4% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       23544004608 B (23.5 GB) (56.6% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk0s3 39A33B75-43D5-47C9-B74F-521A7AF78655
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s3
    |   Size:                       41572282368 B (41.6 GB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s1 F9EFF7D7-4247-31B0-8247-88FB8F0337C9
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s1 (No specific role)
    |   Name:                      DISK0S3 (Case-sensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /
    |   Capacity Consumed:         15245549568 B (15.2 GB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s2 494FE6BC-9C62-4FCB-A59A-F230BDEFD6EF
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s2 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         21774336 B (21.8 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s3 8018FC36-B4C6-48A2-9FBC-684F4496DB9D
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s3 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         517750784 B (517.8 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s4 6CD41126-A22A-417E-BDF6-0758E5F5222C
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s4 (VM)
        Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               /private/var/vm
        Capacity Consumed:         2147504128 B (2.1 GB)
        FileVault:                 No
```

.

```
$sudo gpt -r show disk0

      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  408627792      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  409037432       1416         
  409038848   81195864      3  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  490234712          7         
  490234719         32         Sec GPT table
  490234751          1         Sec GPT header
```

Comment: Did you try asking on the guide page?

Comment: I thought i did but it looks like its not showing up there. And now i don't have enough rep to comment.

Comment: When changing your GUID, did you use the correct size for your partition (the number after `-s` in the command) or did you use the same number as in the guide you linked ?I had a problem similar to yours and the way to fix it was to use the proper size. Also could you update your question with the result of the `gpt -r show disk0` command ?

Comment: I used the correct size.

Comment: I am also having this issue. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: I haven't been able to find a fix yet

Comment: It seems that your APFS container, which was originally 250GB, was shrunk to 40GB and placed at the end of the disk, which may have then yielded a 210GB partition at the start of the disk with the `FFF...FFF` GUID. You have changed the GUID of this 210GB partition to match that of an APFS container, but this does not magically undo a shrink operation or create an APFS container; ...

Comment: ... notice that `diskutil list` displays the name of the APFS container `disk0s3`, but not the partition `disk0s2`, and that `diskutil apfs list` successfully lists the APFS volumes within the APFS container `disk0s3`, but does not display any details for `disk0s2`. That is, it seems that an APFS container superblock is not present at sector 409640 of the disk. Further investigation would be necessary to discover any data or valid APFS container superblocks that might be present elsewhere on the disk.