# Partition Type: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF no backup

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

trying to delete a disk partition, the disks utility has given an error and now the Macintosh HD volume was not in APFS.

But of course, being different, does not match anything with mine. It also seemed to me that the information would not be lost, since it is still in the partition this is badly done

I attach a photo.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixit this problem following this guide

[OS volume shows as type 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff)

Thx all!

Comment: Excellent work. I’ll link these officially, it’s good to not delete anything fen when closed since it helps people find the most useful answers.