# MacBook Pro - can't boot into Windows, how to fix the MBR?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, partition

Following the post [FFFFFFFF problem with hybrid partitioned drive, not able to fix with the guide in other topics](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/358688/ffffffff-partition-problem-not-able-to-fix-with-the-guide-in-other-topics#358688), I was able to fix the FFFFFFFF partition problem and managed to boot into macOS, and now how can I recover bootcamp Windows?

Comment: The info in this post should be in this question : https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/358732/237687

Answer (score 2):

Since your drive was hybrid partitioned, I will assume Windows was setup to legacy BIOS boot. You can confirm this by enter the following command in a Terminal application window.

```
ls /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/Boot/BCD
```

If Windows was set to BIOS boot, then you will get the following response.

```
/Volumes/BOOTCAMP/Boot/BCD
```

Otherwise, you will get the response shown below.

```
ls: /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/Boot/BCD: No such file or directory
```

If the `/Volumes/BOOTCAMP/Boot/BCD` file does not exist, then post a comment.

> Note: The `Boot` folder is marked as hidden, so the `BCD` file will not normally appear in the Finder application.

One problem preventing Windows from booting would be there is no long an partition marked active in the MBR partition table. You can correct this error by running the `fdisk` command, while booted from an external macOS installation disk. The commands to enter are given below.

```
fdisk -e /dev/disk0
flag 3
quit
y
```

An example is given below.

```
$ fdisk -e /dev/disk0
fdisk: could not open MBR file /usr/standalone/i386/boot0: No such file or directory
Enter 'help' for information
fdisk: 1> flag 3
Partition 3 marked active.
fdisk:*1> quit
Writing current MBR to disk.
Device could not be accessed exclusively.
A reboot will be needed for changes to take effect. OK? [n] y
```

If Window still fails to boot, then post a comment.