# Macintosh HD partition missing from startup options

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partition

I tried to shrink my Windows Bootcamp partition using third-party software which led to my Macintosh HD partition missing from startup options. Unfortunately I don't have a recent backup for the whole drive to restore from. If I try to reinstall macOS from scratch it doesn't see the partition either.

[image]

Disk utility sees it but it's greyed out and is being shown as Unmounted without the option to mount it back.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this without wiping out the whole drive and reinstalling everything from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

The second image you posted shows a partition type of `DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC`. This is for a [Windows Recovery Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs) type partition.

From Windows, you can open a Command Prompt window as an Administrator. Next, you could enter the commands given below to change `disk0s2` to an Hierarchical File System Plus (HFS+) type partition.

```
diskpart
select disk 0
select partition 2
set id=48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC override
gpt attributes=0x0000000000000000
exit
```

> Note: This answer assumes you are not using Core Storage.

A more comprehensive solution is given as the accepted answer to the question: [OS volume shows as type 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff). Despite the fact that your partition type is `DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC` and the linked question partition type is `FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF`, the accepted answer provides a solution that would work in your case.