# Mac Partition won't boot after Bootcamp Partition Resize

Tags: mac, bootcamp, partition, efi

I made a huge mistake. I resized my Bootcamp Windows Partition and messed up with my Mac partition; without any data, since my sister needed my backup hard drive for something urgent.

To recover the data, I tried to install a new Mac partition onto the Bootcamp partition.

Now I try to recover the original Mac partition.

These are the outputs:

Testdisk:

```
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

 1 P EFI System                    40     409639     409600 [EF]
 2 P Windows Recovery Env      409640  400800263  400390624 [Ma]
 3 P Mac HFS                400800264  488965175   88164912 [Apple_HFS_Untitled_2]
 4 P Mac Boot               488965176  490234711    1269536 [Recovery HD]


diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2: DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC               205.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS BOOTCAMP                45.1 GB    disk0s3
   4:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s4
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *252.9 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Ohne Titel              252.5 GB   disk1s2
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *31.6 GB    disk2
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 UNTITLED                31.6 GB    disk2s1
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *21.0 MB    disk3
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS rEFIt                   20.9 MB    disk3s2


sudo gpt show disk0
Password:
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  400390624      2  GPT part - DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC
  400800264   88164912      3  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  488965176    1269536      4  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  490234712          7         
  490234719         32         Sec GPT table
  490234751          1         Sec GPT header
Thomass-MacBook-Pro:~ Thomas$
```

Comment: Thanks @klanomath for the quick reply! Is there a standard partition for OS X Catalina? That's the os that was installed before the crash :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The partition GUID of disk0s2 (DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC) is probably wrong. It designates the partition as a Windows Recovery Environment, which is the ugly stepsibling of macOS' recovery partition. Changing the GUID of a partition doesn't modify the volume format! A wrong GUID usually renders a partition unbootable though.

It's rather unclear how and why the GUID has been modified.

Depending on your (former) macOS system version it should be either the GUID of an APFS, a CoreStorage or an HFS+ partition instead. To detect the proper GUID for disk0s2, use the method described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/305712/93229). If you remember the system version the steps to detect the partition type outlined there are usually **not** required.

Here, the system of the broken boot volume is known (macOS 10.5 Catalina). Catalina's boot partition type exclusively is APFS.

---

Then the standard procedure would be:

1. Boot to another boot device (either Internet Recovery/macOS Recovery (alt-cmd-R), another Mac (with the broken Mac attached in Target Disk Mode) or a thumb drive. Preferred system version: the same as the "broken" one. Below I assume you booted to Internet Recovery/macOS Recovery Catalina!
2. Open Terminal and enter:

   ```
   diskutil list
   ```

   to determine the disk number of the internal disk of the "broken" Mac (below I assume it's disk0 - apply accordingly)
3. Get the partition table with gpt:

   ```
   gpt -r show /dev/disk0
   ```

   **Depending on the boot drive you have to prepend `sudo` and/or disable SIP here, if you want to execute `gpt ...`**

   `sudo` is required if you boot to another Mac/thumb drive (sw_vers < 10.15) and using an admin account. `sudo` & disable SIP is required booted to another Mac/thumb drive (sw_vers >= 10.15) and using an admin account. Booting to Internet Recovery 10.15 doesn't require additonal steps.
4. Unmount the broken Mac's internal drive/volumes

   ```
   diskutil umount disk0s3
   diskutil umountDisk disk0
   ```
5. Remove the second partition

   ```
   gpt remove -i 2 /dev/disk0
   ```
6. Unmount the broken Mac's internal drive/volumes

   ```
   diskutil umount disk0s3
   diskutil umountDisk disk0
   ```
7. add the second partition with the proper GUID

   ```
   gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 400390624 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
   ```
8. Verify the disk and the volume

   ```
   diskutil list
   diskutil verifyDisk disk0
   diskutil verifyVolume diskXsY #use the proper diskXsY of the APFS volume in the diskutil list output
   ```

Comment: Thank you @klanomath ! It worked out fine - best guide!

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Wanted to add some value here by saying that I suspect that this happened after using one of these freemium partition move/expand features (Easeus, I think). It required a reboot after applying the changes, wherein I booted into their tool to do it. Fast forward a couple of days and I lost my partition.
There's a slight chance it could've been a rogue Windows 10 update, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe worth noting that "7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC" is a magic number. It's alway this number and not something you need to find somewhere.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).