# MacOS GPT Messed up File System ('FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF')

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, startup, recovery

I had tried dual booting Linux and macOS, and when I rebooted my computer the OS volume shows as type 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'.

I tried following [OS volume shows as type 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff) but I think I'm doing it wrong/making it worse. I did not have a recovery partition, I did have an empty bootcamp partition ~130gb, and I believe it was macOS Catalina on APFS.

[image]

[image: I had played with the partitions a lot, this is what it looks like now.. Probably not correct.]

I had played with the partitions a lot, this is what it looks like now.. Probably not correct.

How can I get back at least the data from my Mac partition?

Answer (score 1):

The first partition (the EFI partition) is mislocated. It should start at block 40 and end at block 409639 (=moved by 6 blocks towards the end of the disk).

In Recovery Mode you can simply remove the first partition and add it again properly aligned:

```
gpt remove -i 1 /dev/disk0
gpt add -i 1 -b 40 -s 409600 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B disk0
```

---

This apparently(?) solved the problem and the Mac booted again properly.

To verify the integrity of the APFS container afterwards enter:

```
diskutil list #to get the device number of the APFS container scheme device (probably disk1)
diskutil verifyVolume disk1
```

The result should be: `Storage system check exit code is 0`!