# Partition type FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF startup volume Macintosh HD

Tags: terminal, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I resized the partitions of my Macbook Pro.
it had the following partitions:
Macintosh HD 415GB
Bootcamp 85GB

After the resizing, it still worked up until I restarted. When I did so all the Drives were gone. In the Terminal of the safe mode, I found my startup volume to be this: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFF.

I followed some similar issues from here and used the Terminal in the Safe Mode but ended up with this now please see the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9ywl.jpg

Now all the drives are gone when I check in the disc utilities and the apple core storage is just 220GB large as you can see on the attached image.

**— Progress 01**

Resized EFI to 409600

Now I need to figure out the type and size of the disks by an inspection. How do I perform an inspection? @David Anderson

**— Progress 02**

I think it is High Sierra (sorry)

I ran:

```
dd if=/dev/disk0s2 count=3 | vis -c
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lolKN.jpg

**— Progress 03**

Corrected the GPT as described and now I see this (like in your screenshot David):

```
-bash-3.2# gpt -r show /dev/disk0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  830799832      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  831209472  145895555         
  977105027         32         Sec GPT table
  977105059          1         Sec GPT header
```

and:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2: 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC               425.4 GB   disk0s2
```

Comment: If you have a backup of your files, now would be the time to use it. Otherwise, to determine if you can recover, you would have to post *exactly* what you did so far. Also, you have not posted the model/year of your Mac or the version of macOS that was installed. In other words, it is difficult to post a solution (if a solution even exists), when you have not posted any information on what you did to create this situation.

Comment: @klanomath: I suppose the OP erased the entire GPT, then entered the values manually. The size of the first partition was probably entered with a missing `6` digit. The starting value of the second partition is probably correct, but the size is probably wrong. The type may also be wrong. As you stated in your previous answers such as [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff/305712#305712), the type and size can be determined by inspection.

Comment: I would say to post the output from `export LC_CTYPE="ASCII";dd if=/dev/disk0s2 count=3 2>/dev/null | vis -cw`. This is basically the same as @klanomath asked for, except the results are invertible.

Comment: The size is 830799832, which is 425 GB. So the command would be `gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 830799832 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0`

Comment: @klanomath: The important part of output you asked for was invertible. You can verify this by entering the command `echo -n 'NXSB\0\^P\0\0\M-{\M^_0\^F\0\0\0\0' | unvis | vis -cw; echo`.  To get the hex values, you need to enter the command `echo -n 'NXSB\0\^P\0\0\M-{\M^_0\^F\0\0\0\0' | unvis | hexdump -Cv`. The sequence `fb 9f 30 06` is equal to `103849979`. Multiply by `8` to get `830799832`.

Comment: When done correcting the GPT, the result should be [this](https://imgur.com/a/F3UEevJ).

Comment: Restart the Mac and see if you boot to macOS,

Comment: Restarted now: "No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press key"

Comment: If you boot to the Startup Manager, do you see a macOS icon? If you do, can you select the label below the icon to boot to macOS? You can boot to the Startup Manager by restarting the Mac and immediately holding down the option key.

Comment: Even if I start-up holding the option key, it ends up at a black screen with: "No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press key"

Comment: yes I do have a thumb drive.

Comment: @PhpSch Please install a full system (10.13-10.15) on the **empty** thumb drive and some remote desktop app (e.g. [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/)). Then I can check & (hopefully)  recover it from remote...

Comment: Thank you @Klanomath, I will do this and come back as soon as I am ready!

Comment: @PhpSch Please mail the credentials to klanomath@googlemail.com. **Don't post them here!**