# Problem internal partition macOS high sierra

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, partition, recovery

Please help me, this is my last year at university, and all my files and projects are on my device.  I had two sections 399 gigs for the Mac system and 100 gaps on which I installed Linux .. After a while I deleted the Linux and upon restart I couldn't log in and some solutions worked out but the problem still exists. 
[image]
[image]

### Update:

[image]

Thanks, the answer worked, but I have this problem: When I start my compute, it goes to EFI boot, I think it's for windows 10. I don't need it. I want to delete it and put my priority macOS. How i can do that? I'm soooo scare to do any things.

And, I can't see the 100 GB partition.
[image]

Comment: It would be really helpful to document what you did to delete Linux and what those *some solutions* that worked out were.

Comment: Please ..

Comment: I'm destroy the gpt and created agian But it's still not work .. my internal partition it's unmount i can't mounted

Comment: Can you post the output from the following command? `export LC_CTYPE="ASCII"; dd if=/dev/disk0s2 count=1 | vis -c`

Comment: Well I added the picture that  you asked for in my question, you can see it ..

Comment: Can you help me 

Comment: Now that things seem to be accessible, there's an important thing to do before going much further: **MAKE BACKUPS OF EVERYTHING IMPORTANT!** If something important is only on that computer, it can be lost to any of a variety of problems. I'd recommend multiple backup copies (kept in different places) of anything really important. If you know where all the important things are, manually copying them to something like flash drives *might* be sufficient. But a proper backup program (or two, one for macOS & one for Windows) would be even better. Or both!

Comment: We get a question similar to your question quite often here at Ask Different. Therefore, I will asked that this question be marked as a duplicate of this question:  [OS volume shows as type 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff). If you need further help, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You made partition 2 type `53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`. You should have made partition 2 type `7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`.

The commands to change the type are given below. I assume you are entering the commands from macOS Recovery or from a installation flash drive.

```
gpt remove -i 2 /dev/disk0
gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 781050984 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
```

### Update:

Do the following to make macOS the default.

Hold down the control key when you choose Untitled.

I am not sure what you did to merge the 100 GB partition back to the APFS container. This was in explained in my answer. However, the results you posted in your update look good.