# Apple bootable drive converted to fffffff type and getting issue of resource busy

Tags: partition, startup

In tried the situation on [OS volume shows as type 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff?newreg=0a972fe7b05b45deaf6d07026c5990a1)
But still getting error of resource busy. Even in tried diskutil umount disk0s2 still same error.
Please help.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff?newreg=0a972fe7b05b45deaf6d07026c5990a1 even tried the solution on this page but getting error of resource busy.

Comment: How are you starting up? Are you using Internet Recovery mode, Recovery from the local disk, an external disk, or what?

Comment: I'm using internet recovery mode and trying the method on the page in the above but when I'm trying to remove the disk0s2 using gpt command- gpt remove -i 2 disk0. I'm getting error that resource busy. I have tried diskutil umount disk0 also diskutil umount disk0s2 It says disk already unmounted

Comment: Which version of Internet Recovery are you using? The can be determined from the output of the `sw_vers` command. If version 10.13 or higher, then you can use the `-f` option for the `gpt` command to do a shared lock. For example: `gpt -f remove -i 2 disk0`. Also, make sure the current working directory is not on `drive0`.

Comment: My recovery version was 10.12 but your commnd of gpt -f worked. Thank you very very much.