# gpt add: disk0: error: no space available on device

Tags: partition, startup

I’m having boot issues and attempting to follow the instructions outlined in the accepted answer here: [OS volume shows as type 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff)

I’ve been able to remove volume 2 with gpt, but attempting to re-add the volume with correct type results in an error: `gpt add: disk0: error: no space available on device`

Am I using the command incorrectly?
What should I do to properly re-add the volume?
Is rebooting at this point going to cause any problems?

Original question: [No bootable device - High Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431642/no-bootable-device-high-sierra)

[image]
[image]

Comment: The partition 2 all ready exist. You have first to delete it before re-create.

Comment: @Jean_JD I ran ‘gpt remove -i 2 disk0’ and the result is what can be seen in the 2nd photo: MBR part 255 photo 1 is from before the volume was removed

Comment: @DavidAnderson I don’t feel that the language chosen in the above comment is necessary, conducive to a civil discussion or in line with stack exchanges guidelines. I have read your answer, it seemed to leave the task of deciding what kind of MBR I have in my hands. As I have no prior knowledge of this or knowledge of how to determine this fact I proceeded on the basis that your linked duplicate answer was appropriate. If that was not your intent I welcome you to to clarify your response.

Comment: I believe the accepted procedure is edit the original question, then ask for the question to be reopened. Or, I think the question ends up a queue where the question gets reviewed. Posting a new question can result in the new question being closed. A lot of these [FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF type questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF) have be asked before. Usually someone who is asking a new question has not researched the existing answers enough.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I'm not sure what to tell you, the duplicate notification box on the original question literally says `Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one.`  If those instructions are contrary to accepted procedure I don't feel that it's productive to have them listed: I can say for a fact that  at least one person has followed them.

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/fMkrbip) is what I am seeing. Can you post an image of what you are seeing? I would like to check this with a moderator. (Maybe this is a question for [meta](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com). Probably a duplicate.) I was going to flag your new question for closure at the 24 hour mark. (Which was a little while ago.) Would you not rather concentrate on finding an answer, rather that bickering over the mechanics of the procedures?

Comment: Rather that adding a new answer to another posted `FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF` type question, a new answer was posted to [OS volume shows as type 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff), which should fix the problem stated in this question.