# Unable to add back storage from Linux partition after deleting ( FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF Drive)

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

This is embarrassing.... I want to Linux distro hop but first I need all the spaces from my partition for something before that. So, I mindlessly followed apple's guide on deleting partition, and surprise surprise: I failed.

diskutil list:

[image: diskutil list]

It's only after googling more about this that I found out that my hard drive have this weird FFFFFF type and that's apparently bad news.

[image: I am screwed]

Not sure if this is relevant at all, but in my Disk Utility, I saw something that I normally didn't see before. Normally, it would only show my hard drive (The second one in the list). But here I saw another one.... which is also coincidentally my hard drive (Normally, if I put it to show all devices, the second volume in the list would be under this volume. But now, they're completely seperate). And of course, the second volume, is still showing the same capacity with no added storage from the partition.

I'm just really damn confused on this matter altogether, the gist of what I want is that I want to fix the FFFFFF volume/drive thing and make everything back to normal. But, well I need to seek some guidance on this because I don't really know what I should do next. I'm currently just not shutting down the device at all and using it semi-normally I guess.

Comment: Post the output from `diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Offset -e Size`. And maybe `sudo dd if=/dev/disk0s2 bs=512 count=1 | hexdump -Cv`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Okay, here's the output: https://imgur.com/a/xpNnUWA

Comment: What is your current startup disk?

Comment: @DavidAnderson It's supposed to be my SSD but I booted back on my hard drive to clean some stuff out.

Comment: Never mind. I assume you Mac is fixed now?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yeah everything is back to normal now. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of some previous question. I assume at some point your question will be flagged as a duplicate. All that does is prevent others from answering and prevents others will low reputations from viewing. You will still be able to view, edit and comment on this question.

Comment: Your question is not exactly the same as this question: [OS volume shows as type 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff), but your question is close enough to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot to macOS Recovery. Enter `diskutil list` to verify the `FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFF` partition is still `disk0s2`. Enter the following commands.

```
gpt -f remove -i 2 disk0
gpt -f add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 1269426984 -t apfs disk0
```

Comment: After doing this and adding back free spaces in Disk Utility. My issue seems to be fixed altogether. Thank you!