# Startup Disk Cannot be found (cannot reinstall macOS from Disk Utility in Recovery Mode)

Tags: macos, disk-utility, bootcamp, startup, mount

Last night, I was booted my MacBook Pro and it was working find, after a few minutes restarted my MacBook Pro with Bootcamp. But then it showed a screen with a circle a line through it. I noticed that my MBP was kind hot ( unusual after using it for few minutes).

I did reboot MBP in internet recovery mode, but did not help. MPB boots in Windows 7 bootcamp with no issues. According to apple help,
I did try to recover the disk in Disk Utility, it did not work. As you can see the is no issue with the main drive. It shows two partitions: Dsisk2s2 & BootCamp.

[image: two partitions: disk2s2 & BootCamp]

My files are on disk2s2 shown below, however, as you can see both Verify Disk and Repair Disk buttons are dimmed! When I click on Mount botton, nothing happens. I did also try to mount it from File menu, but was not helpful.

[image]

Next I tried to see if I can reinstall MacOS ( the version installed was Mac Mojave). The reinstallation of MacOS ( although Mountain Lion), was unsuccessful as it only shows BootCamp partition which is locked and cannot reinstall MacOS in it.

[image]

Is there anyway I can without erasing the Partition fix my MBP. This is my music studio main computer and I have tons of software and files in it.

I do appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you tell us… what options you see if you boot holding down the Option key [Alt] & also what you see if you start from 'regular' recovery [Cmd/R at the chimes]. Part of the issue I can see when you're booted from Internet Recovery is you have an *old* Recovery [the '3D' dots in window corners are a dead giveaway]. Mountain Lion cannot see APFS formatted drives, which is what Mojave will be - that's why it's just showing disk2s2 instead of the volume name.

Comment: Thank you so much. holding down the Option key [Alt]: Only Windows to select. holding down the Option key [Alt]: Starting Internet recovery This may take a while. What is the fix then, please?

Comment: We don't know yet, because the version of Recovery cannot see your boot drive anyway. You need to get into a Recovery that is new enough, before you can do any diagnosis. Internet recovery ought to use the latest version your Mac can run. The first useful sign when it loads is that the dots top left will be 'flat' colours https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIoRX.png , not 3D https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw3ZL.png

Comment: can't I create a Mac Mojave bootable installer for macOS - instruction on Apple Support or create a bootable recovery on a flash drive and run them w.o. losing my files?

Comment: @Tetsujin: Isn't this just another one of those darn `FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF` problems?

Comment: Yes. I have another mac next to me. Shouldn't I create a bootable installer on a flash drive https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372? my only concern is I might lose my files. But I can remove the hard driver and put it in hard disk enclosure and do a back.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - it could be indeed. I just wanted to be able to see the drive from something that will properly recognise it.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Could be? Look at the OP's second image. You can see `disk2s2` partition type is `FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - Hawkeye. I didn't spot that ;))

Comment: chikitin: Can you boot to Windows 7 and post the output from the command `echo list disk | diskpart`? You will need to enter the command in an "Administrator: Command Prompt" window. In other words "Run as administrator" when opening a "Command Prompt" window.

Comment: chikitin: From Windows 7, could you also post the output from the command `echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%`?

Comment: echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% -> AMD64

Comment: echo list disk | diskpart =>                                                                                                              Microsfot DiskPart Version 6.1.7.1.7601                                                                   Disk ###/ Disk 0 , Status/Online Size/447 GB Free/0B. below the Dyn and Gpt, nothing is listed.

Answer (score 0):

### Duplicate Question

A question is often considered to be a duplicate if one or more of the posted answers to the earlier question can be applied to both questions. In your case, your question is a duplicate of the question [OS volume shows as type 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff), where the partition type is APFS. However, I would encourage you to use the alternative simpler solution given below.

---

### Alternate Simpler Solution

The following steps will fix an error in the GUID Partition Table (GPT) stored on the Mac's internal drive.

1. Boot to Windows 7.
2. Download the project [GPT fdisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/). This should place the file `gdisk-windows-1.0.9.zip` in your Downloads folder.
3. Use the Windows Explorer to copy the `gdisk64.exe` and `sgdisk64.exe` from the `gdisk-windows-1.0.9.zip` file to your Downloads folder.
4. Open an "Administrator: Command Prompt" window and enter the following commands.

   ```
   cd /d %userprofile%\Downloads
   sgdisk64 -t 2:af0a 0:
   ```

---

### References

- [An sgdisk Walkthrough](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/sgdisk-walkthrough.html)
- [A gdisk Walkthrough](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/walkthrough.html)

Comment: Thank you, after I did your step 4. I restarted my computer with Alt and it showed two bootable (Windows 7 and Macintosh HD). After I chose Macintosh HD to boot, it showed the cirle with a line trough it! When I did internet recovery, It change the Partion type to 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC instead of FFF. What should I do please? Thank you very mcuh again.

Comment: You can try using Option-Command-R key combination during startup. This might offer the latest macOS that is compatible with your Mac. Open a Terminal window and enter the commands `sw_vers` and `diskutil list internal`. Post the output to your question.

Comment: $ sw_vers > Mac OS X, 10.15.7, BuildVersion 19.H2.   $diskutil list internal > Terminal - _ _bash - 80×10
/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
B:
TYPE NAME
1:APFS Container Scheme
2:Physical Store disk@s2
3:APFS Volume Preboot
4:APFS Volume Recovery

APFS Volume VM APFS Volume Macintosh HD -bash-3.2# SIZE
+374.4 GB
24.1 MB
507.6 MB
1.1 GB
164.1 GB
IDENTIFIER disk2 disk2s2 disk2s3 disk2s4 disk2s5

Comment: Yes, it offers Catalina. Due to old hardware, I should install Mojave and not 10.15. I uploaded the screenshot: https://ibb.co/cTpZBwW

Comment: My disk utility changed, please find an image of my Disk Utility at https://ibb.co/wM5z4pW

Comment: Is there any hope, please? If not, I will take the drive off and copy my data at least! -- Thank you.

Comment: I do not know why you can not boot to Mojave. Your latest Disk Utility image shows the `Macintosh HD` volume is not mounted. If you can not get this volume to mount, then you can not even make a copy of your data. You can try posting the output from the commands `fdisk /dev/disk0` and `gpt -r show disk0`.

Comment: the output from the commands fdisk /dev/disk0 and gpt -r show disk0 are in the picture: https://ibb.co/89YSMq8.      There is a commercial tool ( not free) that claims I can view and copy my files! So, if I disassemble my HDD and put it in an enclosure, wouldn't I be able to see and copy my files?

Comment: It seems the Macintosh HD is disk2s5. I did both commands with disk2 as well as you can see: https://ibb.co/yBhvVMJ.