# Is it possible somehow recover HD on a MacBook Pro 2015? FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF Partition type

Tags: macos, hard-drive, data-recovery

I tried to play with Ubuntu as a second OS on my oldish laptop and was not successful in getting a bootable OS. I faced some problems during installation and decided to go back, but now my Mac shows this image:

[image: Startup disk unavailable]

I recovered the macOS onto my USB drive and built a "new system" on the flash drive with memory of 64 GB. I am on OS X Yosemite.

And now, I would like to access my old disk, mount it somehow or recover from its base. There is no backups, of course.

So, below is how my disks now look and I do not have a clue what to do next.

[image: Number1]
[image: Number2]

Maybe someone could assist me or walk through the process of recovering the Mac to a bootable state (ideally without losing files not backed up)?

---

### Update 1

I did this, as David Anderson asked:

```
recos-MacBook-Pro:~ recos$ sudo dd if=/dev/disk0s2 count=3 | hexdump
Password:
3+0 records in
3+0 records out
1536 bytes transferred in 0.001115 secs (1377475 bytes/sec)
0000000 17 d1 de 5b d2 e8 85 88 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000010 64 75 70 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 80 00 00 00 00
0000020 4e 58 53 42 00 10 00 00 74 3e 7c 02 00 00 00 00
0000030 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000040 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 69 dc e2 50 db bf 45 73
0000050 af 72 b8 87 ba fc 44 a5 20 ca 88 00 00 00 00 00
0000060 65 75 70 00 00 00 00 00 18 01 00 00 1c 6c 00 00
0000070 34 81 05 00 00 00 00 00 f3 ff 04 00 00 00 00 00
0000080 44 00 00 00 94 0f 00 00 42 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
0000090 8f 0f 00 00 05 00 00 00 9e c7 88 00 00 00 00 00
00000a0 19 7d 08 00 00 00 00 00 01 04 00 00 00 00 00 00
00000b0 00 00 00 00 64 00 00 00 02 04 00 00 00 00 00 00
00000c0 08 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 0a 04 00 00 00 00 00 00
00000d0 0c 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 f2 bd 01 00 00 00 00 00
00000e0 f4 bd 01 00 00 00 00 00 1b ca 88 00 00 00 00 00
00000f0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
*
00003d0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7e 18 77 16 00 00 00 00
00003e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
*
00004f0 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9b 49 99 00 00 00 00 00
0000500 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000510 b1 49 99 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000520 01 00 04 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000530 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
*
0000560 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 a6 5e 4b 17 df 06 00
0000570 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
*
0000600
recos-MacBook-Pro:~ recos$
```

---

### Update 2

I did this, as David Anderson asked:

```
recos-MacBook-Pro:~ recos$ sudo gpt -r show disk0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  333575072      2  GPT part - FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF
  333984712  156250007         
  490234719         32         Sec GPT table
  490234751          1         Sec GPT header
recos-MacBook-Pro:~ recos$
```

---

### Update 3

Below is an updated screenshot, which was taken and entering the commands given in David Anderson's answer.

[image: Here we go]

Comment: One possible answer to your question can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff).

Comment: I wish, I could understand, what to do here...

Comment: Can you open a Terminal application window and enter the command `sudo dd if=/dev/disk0s2 count=3 | hexdump`, then post the output to your question?

Comment: Did it, @DavidAnderson

Comment: Your output shows `disk0s2` is APFS formatted. The next step would be to get the start and size values from the GUID Partition Table (GPT). Enter the command `sudo gpt -r show disk0` and post the output to your question.

Comment: @DavidAnderson, did it!

Comment: I asked for this question to be closed, because the question is a duplicate of [OS volume shows as type 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff)

Comment: @bmike: I think the OP was trying to say the Mac was booted to Yosemite while fixing the internal drive. Clearly, the internal drive did not have Yosemite installed, because `disk0s2` was APFS formatted. Do you think the question should not be closed?

Comment: Oops. I may have made it worse. Closure should help that though. Feel free to fix my edit if needed @DavidAnderson. As always, your care and expertise are so much appreciated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the following commands

```
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
sudo gpt remove -i 2 disk0
sudo gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 333575072 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
```

When finished do the following:

1. Shutdown the Mac.
2. Remove the flash drive.
3. Startup the Mac.

Comment: Did all commands you asked, now I can see another partition type on a disk (uploaded screenshot on the original post). But I can not mount it

Comment: You can not mount APFS from Yosemite. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! You saved my computer life! @DavidAnderson

Comment: I am glad your Mac booted! Actually, it was [klanomath's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff/305712#305712) that fixed your Mac. If you have not already done so, you might want to up vote his answer. I am going to ask that your question be closed as a duplicate question.