Macbook Pro 2013 - Unable to boot after attempting to remove Kali Linux partition
After attempting to remove a Kali Linux partition through Disk Utility on macOS High Sierra, I ended up with a drive that had a type of just FFFFFFF-FFFFF.
I proceeded to try to fix that through using Internet Recovery, where I entered the following commands into Terminal:
gpt -r show disk0

diskutil umountDisk disk0

gpt remove -i 2 disk0

gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 431203056 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC  disk0

This removed the partition type from being F, however, I am unsure if that led to the fact that I cannot access the drive's full storage. (I also somehow have 24 partitions...)
I am now looking to reinstall macOS through Internet Recovery, but I cannot even mount my largest volume, disk0s2, which results in a fatal error.
I have attached several photos of the situation, and unsure of what to do next.
Please help!!


Where did you get the value 431203056?

I took it from a similar Apple stack exchange article which was similar to my problem. I stupidly followed and inputted the command without checking.

That value is the size of the partition in sectors. Any value taken from another Apple stack exchange article would most likely be wrong.

I see... No wonder my drives are all over the place.

In your question, you show you entered gpt -r show disk0 before making changes. Do you still have this output? BTW: The "drives are all over the place" has nothing to do with your problem. Having extra drives is normal when booting to Recovery.

Ah sorry I did not see your comment. Yes I still have the same output

What is the start and size values for the row with an index of 2?

Same as in the photo, 409640 for start and 431203056. Both have not changed

Can you provide a link to the Apple stack exchange article you used?

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff/305712#305712 < Article here. I referred to the instructions of the pinned answer, using the commands for Higher Sierra [APFS] (I am not fully available right now, so I might have to get back to any comments later.)

Post the output from the command diskutil unmountdisk disk0 followed by dd if=/dev/disk0s2 count=1 2>/dev/null | LC_CTYPE=ASCII vis -cfw.

Please don't post text as an image; see Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?.

@agarza: You can ask for the OP to not post text as an image, however the OP is using Internet Recovery where copying from Terminal to Safari is difficult for the average user. Furthermore, if the version of Internet Recovery is than same the installed High Sierra, then there can be compatibility issues between Safari and Ask Different's webpages.

@DavidAnderson I have updated the post to include the output of the command you suggested.

You entered the following commands.
gpt -r show disk0
diskutil umountDisk disk0
gpt remove -i 2 disk0
gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 431203056 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC  disk0

You should have entered the following commands.
gpt -r show disk0
diskutil umountDisk disk0
gpt remove -i 2 disk0
diskutil umountDisk disk0
gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 820312496 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0

Try entering these commands.

Removing Linux partition by use of the diskutil command or the Disk Utility application can result in an APFS partition's type being changed to FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF, which basically is the integer value of -1. I mention this because you still have a Linux partition on disk0.
If you wanted to remove the Linux partition at disk0s3, you could do the following from Internet Recovery. Here, I assume the command gpt -r show disk0 still produces the following line.
  820723712 154380288      3  GPT - 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4

The commands below change the Linux partition to an ExFAT formatted Windows partition.
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
gpt remove -i 3 disk0
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
gpt add -i 3 -b 820723712 -s 154380288 -t windows disk0
diskutil umountDisk disk0
newfs_exfat -v MyExFAT /dev/disk0s3

The command below should remove the partition. This should include writing zeros to the start of the partition and sorting the GPT in ascending order.
diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3


I attempted to execute the last command, and it returned an error of "gpt add: unable to open device 'disk0': Resource busy. This came after I was able to execute the first 3 commands without error.

I suppose I should have caught that. Probably needed to do diskutil umountDisk disk0 before entering the command. I updated my answer.

Thank you for the help! I can now boot back into Macintosh HD safely, the drive is fully recognised. One more thing however, is there a way to safely and properly remove the Linux Filesystem partition? (I have updated the post to include an image showing this)
