# Unable to boot into macOS or Ubuntu after dd and partition reduction

Tags: backup, unix, efi

I am on an early 2015 MacBook Pro with macOS Sierra, dual boot with Ubuntu 16.04.

In macOS, I did `dd if=/dev/disk1s3 of=disk2s2`(if i remember correctly). It succeeded and I proceeded to shrink the macOS partition using Disk Utility. That succeeded too. I proceeded to reboot and found myself unable to boot into any systems. Going into recovery mode, I am unable to restore from a backup or reinstall a new macOS.

I see the partitions as they are supposed to be, though their health would be suspect. I have

```
210mb EFI partition as /dev/sda1 FAT
182GB macOS parition as /dev/sda2 ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff
30GB free space partition as /dev/sda
30GB Ubuntu PArtition as /dev/sda4 Ext4
4GB Linux Swap as /dev/sda5 Swap
```

Would anyone know how I could restore things as they are? I am looking to install rEFInd so my MacBook would provide the option without me having to hold the Option key everytime.

`diskutil list` returns:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                   TYPE NAME                SIZE        IDENTIFIER
   0:  GUID_partition_scheme                     *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                    EFI EFI                 209.7 MB    disk0s1
   2: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF       181.8 GB    disk0s2
   3: 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4       30.0 GB     disk0s4
   4:                  LINUX SWAP                4.0 GB      disk0s5
/dev/disk1
   #:                   TYPE NAME                SIZE        IDENTIFIER
   0: Apple_partition_scheme                     *1.3 GB     disk0
   1:    Apple_partition_map                     30.7 KB     disk0s1
   2:              Apple_HFS OSX X Base System   1.3 GB      disk0s2
/dev/disk2
   #:                  TYPE NAME                 SIZE        IDENTIFIER
   0:                       untitled             *524.3 KB   disk2
/dev/disk3
   #:                  TYPE NAME                 SIZE        IDENTIFIER
   0:                       untitled             *524.3 KB   disk3
/dev/disk4
   #:                  TYPE NAME                 SIZE        IDENTIFIER
   0:                       untitled             *524.3 KB   disk4 
/dev/disk5
   #:                  TYPE NAME                 SIZE        IDENTIFIER
   0:                       untitled             *524.3 KB   disk5
/dev/disk6
   #:                  TYPE NAME                 SIZE        IDENTIFIER 
   0:                   untitled                 *524.3 KB   disk6
/dev/disk7 
   #:                  TYPE NAME                 SIZE        IDENTIFIER
   0:                       untitled             *6.3 MB     disk7
/dev/disk8
   #:                  TYPE NAME                 SIZE        IDENTIFIER
   0:                       untitled             *2.1 MB     disk8
/dev/disk9
   #:                  TYPE NAME                 SIZE        IDENTIFIER
   0:                       untitled             *1.0 MB     disk9
/dev/disk10
   #:                  TYPE NAME                 SIZE        IDENTIFIER
   0:                       untitled             *524.3 KB   disk10
/dev/disk11
   #:                  TYPE NAME                 SIZE        IDENTIFIER
   0:                       untitled             *524.3 KB   disk11
/dev/disk12  
   #:                  TYPE NAME                 SIZE        IDENTIFIER
   0:                       untitled             *1.0 MB     disk12
```

Update:  removed/destroyed disk0 via gpt. just before I `gpt add` partitions back.

```
    /dev/disk0
   #:                   TYPE NAME                SIZE        IDENTIFIER
   0:  FDisk_partition_scheme                    *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                    0xEE                    209.7 MB    disk0s1
   2:                    0xDA                    181.8 GB    disk0s2
   3:                   Linux                    30.0 GB     disk0s4
```

Update 2: Adding back the partitions. (I neglected adding back -i 3 and -i 2 respectively)

```
    start        size        index        contents
        0           1                     PMBR
        1           1                     Pri GPT header
        2          32                     Pri GPT table
       34           6               
       40      409600            1        GPT part - C12A7328.....
   409640   226802864            3        GPT part - 5374GF72.....
227212504     1269536            2        GPT part - 426F6F74.....
228482040   261752679              
490234719          32                     SEC GPT table
490234751           1                     SEC GPT header
```

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/266490/120171) it may lead you in the right direction.  Cheers!

Comment: @bjbk Thanks for that link! It's really insightful. I'd need more help before I can customise that solution for my problem. So all my partitions except the macOS partition are intact and healthy. The macOS partition is corrupted somehow? That dosent explain why I wouldnt be able to boot into Ubuntu since my EFI partition is outside the macOS one.

Comment: @David would you be able to give more detailed steps? I don’t see where in gdisk I can change UUID, only GUID. I’m still learning my LPIC-101 exams hence still rough around the edges. Alternatively, an apple-centric solution would be great too.

Comment: This is the better answer: [Data Not Backed Up, Partition Type: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/282552/93229) than the one linked in bjbk's comment. Compared to my answer there, **you have to remove disk0s2 only** and re-add it properly.

Comment: @klanomath Hahaha. Looks like I have messed up something between posting the two outputs. How would I go about backing up my machine before removing any partitions (If possible at all)

Comment: Removing a partition and re-adding it with the proper type (and previous sizes) with gpt only alters the partition table. The **content** of the partition won't be deleted.

Comment: There was an instruction that involves destruction. Could you educate on what that does? Instruction in question: dd if=/dev/disk0s2 count=3 | vis -c

Comment: It's similar to a hexdump (which isn't available in recovery mode). It reads the first 3 blocks of disk0s2 and pipes it to vis. The output is more or less human readable. The purpose is to detect the correct partition type: either CoreStorage or HFS+ Journaled. Depending on the result of dd|vis different commands + options have to be executed to reinstate your macos volume.

Comment: @klanomath  
On `gpt remove -i 3 disk0` I had the error: Suspicious MBR at sector0. `diskutil umount disk0s0` returned Unmount failed for disk0s0. – EraserPencil 9 hours ago

Comment: There is nothing like a disk0s0 - nowhere in macOS disk management! Please read the answers/instructions more thoroughly! The proper command to unmount a disk is `diskutil umountDisk disk0` and to unmount a volume/partition `diskutil umount disk0s2`.

Comment: @klanomath Yea! `diskutil umountDisk disk0` was sucessful, `gpt remove -i 3 disk0` gave: Suspicious MBR at sector 0. Since it was an error not listed in the provided solution, I interpretated it as "if I get an error message, unmount the disk again or unmount stubborn volumes with `diskutil umount disk0sX`" in a desperate vain attempt.

Comment: The suspicious MBR was installed by Ubuntu/grub or whatever. It shouldn't matter in the first place. It can be fixed in a second step like in this question: [How to fix broken GPT, GUID and unmountable, no type volumes?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/221114/how-to-fix-broken-gpt-guid-and-unmountable-no-type-volumes)

Comment: @klanomath I think I'm on my way to sucessfully restore everything. This is a little extra on the top. I've been meaning to install rEFInd instead of GRUB 2 so I wouldnt need to constantly hold the option key to boot into Ubuntu. Do you have any advice on that?

Comment: Please ask an extra question!

Comment: @klanomath `gpt -r show disk0` matches your output on the solution, however `diskutil  verifyDisk disk0` outputs: Problems were found with the partition map which might prevent booting. Error:  -69808: Some information as unavailble during an interval lookup. I proceeded only with you instruction and did not explore rEFInd. Update: I neglected to add "-i 3" and "-i 2" respectively.

Comment: The output of `gpt -r show disk0` shouldn't match the output of the answer over there, but **your** previous `gpt -r show disk0` except that the MBR was replaced with a pMBR and the FFFFFF.. partition was replaced with a corestorage or hfs+ partition with the same size as the FFFF partition!

Comment: @klanomath sounds like I messed up badly. any advice on corrections?

Comment: Yes, install a full macOS and TeamViewer to a thumb drive/external disk and invite me to a remote desktop session. **The ffff partition had a size of 181.8 GB (= ~355078125 blocks). Now your mac volume has a size of 226802864 blocks (= ~ 116 GB)! Where did you get those values of your "new" partition?**

Comment: Check the Terminal window(s)/tab(s) by scrolling upwards whether a gpt output of your original disk is still there and post it here!

Comment: @klanomath It is no longer there.

Comment: Then the first sentence in my comment 11 minutes ago "... install a full macOS ... thumb drive ..." becomes effective...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69474/discussion-between-eraserpencil-and-klanomath).

Answer (score 1):

Since you can execute a live version of Ubuntu, you have access to the `gdisk` command. Once booted to Ubuntu, you will need to open a Terminal window. From the Ubuntu desktop, press the <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> keys. A Terminal window should appear, as shown below.

[image: ubu10]

You can confirm partition `/dev/sda2` is a possible "Mac OS Extended" (Journaled)" volume by entering the command given below.

```
sudo  dd  if=/dev/disk1s2  count=3  |  hexdump  -Cv
```

The output at offset `00000400` should appear similar to what is shown below. What is important find is the characters `HFSJ`.

```
00000400  48 2b 00 04 80 00 21 00  48 46 53 4a 00 00 05 4b  |H+....!.HFSJ...K|
```

The interactive command `gdisk` can be used to change the type id of a partition. The example below assumes the partition where macOS resides is a single Mac OS Extended (Journaled) volume. The example will change type id for partition 2 to `48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`. The command to enter is shown below.

```
sudo  gdisk  /dev/sda
```

The interactive input/output is shown below.

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.0

Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
partition table automatically reloaded!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): t
Partition number (1-5): 2
Current type is 'Unknown'
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = AF00): af00
Changed type of partition to 'Apple HFS/HFS+'

Command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/disk1.
Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
partition table automatically reloaded!
Warning: The kernel may continue to use old or deleted partitions.
You should reboot or remove the drive.
The operation has completed successfully.
```

> Note: You can set the default boot volume by holding down the control key before selecting the icon shown in the Mac Startup Manager.

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for that solution. However, my live linux can't detect wifi for some reason, but I don't wanna troubleshoot that now. Is there something we could do from the Internet Recovery Mode? I really hate popping by an Apple store cause I know I will lose my laptop for sure.