# Can't reclaim empty space on main macOS partition [macOS Mojave]

Tags: disk-utility, mojave, partition

A while ago I made a linux partition on my MBP (2017), but it didn't work so well so I needed to delete the partition.  After a lot of trouble trying to delete it, I found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/334506/366960) answer; I used the second part to free the space on the old linux partition, and then I resized it to 0.  Only, it didn't actually resize.  The partition is still there (though it is no longer showing up in Disk Utility):

```bsh
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         276.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                        EFI NO NAME                 629.1 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +276.5 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            246.9 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 45.9 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                510.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

I think it is this line that is the culprit, though I am not sure:

```bsh
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         276.5 GB   disk0s2
```

As I say, I have run

```bsh
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

As per the linked answer, but nothing changed.  Even in recovery mode, Disk Utility will only show the ~277 GB I have available on the main partition.

How can I reclaim this space, which is no longer actually showing up?

---

P.S., this is what I had before I ran those commands:

```bsh
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         276.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                        EFI NO NAME                 629.1 MB   disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Untitled                222.7 GB   disk0s4
   5:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s5

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +276.5 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            249.7 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 45.9 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                510.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      6.4 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            NO NAME                +10.7 GB    disk3
```

`NO NAME` was just a USB drive, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first remove the second EFI partition. Enter the commands given below.

```
diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

Explanation:

The `disk0s3` slice occurs after the `disk0s2` slice. The free space exists after the `disk0s3` slice. The command `diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3` will remove the `disk0s3` slice from the partition table, thus increase the size of the free space. The `diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0` command can then be used to add the free space to the `disk0s2` slice. In other words, `disk0s3` is in the way and is preventing you from adding the free space to `disk0s2`.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much.  Can you explain why that was the solution?

Comment: I update my answer.