# macOS partition startup Volume type FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, recovery, diskutil

I have encountered a nearly identical issue to the one [in this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238012/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffff-after-attempting-to-d#) (and this too: [Data Not Backed Up, Partition Type: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282550/data-not-backed-up-partition-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff)), but my hard drive's main partition is formatted in APFS. When I tried correcting the GUID error as shown in the answer, after reaching the step in which the following command: `gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 372637568 -t APFS /disk0` had to be entered, it returned an error: `usage: gpt add [-b lba] [-i index] [-s lba] [-t uuid] device ...`.

[image: screen shot of the previous configuration]

I cannot boot into macOS, my computer is in internet recovery environment. What's the uuid of the new APFS format? I cannot seem to find it anywhere in the web, and my computer isn't detecting the type of the main macOS partition.
My computer's model: MacBook Pro late 2013.
My data is not backed up and I would really love to recover it.
Update:  `gpt -r show disk0`:

[image: screen shot of the previous configuration]

Update:
I created a MacOS High Sierra Installation disk, and rebooted to it. The new disk utility does not recognize the disk0s2 partition at all, and `diskutil list` included the size of the main osx partition in `GUID_partition_scheme` part of the disk. Would it be possible (and how) to recover the data of the deleted partition (s2) if I reinstalled macOS on an existing unused partition (the Linux partition disk0s4)?
[image: disk utility]
[image: diskutil list] 
[image: gpt -r show disk0]

Comment: try with `... -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC ...` instead of `... -t apfs ...`! Maybe your recovery  boot system is too old and gpt doesn't recognize the apfs argument. AFAIK only 10.12 and 10.13 recovery system's gpt binary can deal with `... - t apfs ...`.

Comment: @klanomath it returned an error: `gpt add: /dev/disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0` and `gpt add: /dev/disk0: error: no space available on device`

Comment: Please update the `gpt -r show disk0` output to check what replaced partition 2!

Comment: @marklark Taking screenshots works neither in the legacy recovery mode, nor the Internet Recovery which I was stuck in

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The proper GUID of APFS partitions is 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC.

The default pMBR was replaced with an old-style MBR, probably by the Linux installation!

Your boot system (in Internet Recovery Mode) seems pretty old. Any disk or partition verification executed with diskutil may yield some bogus result. **In no case try to repair anything with diskutil!**

---

To get your APFS partition back remove partition disk0s2 and restore it with the proper type:

- Open in the menubar > Utilities > Terminal
- get some details:

  ```
  diskutil list #below I assume the disk identifier of the internal disk is disk0
  gpt -r show disk0
  ```
- Unmount disk0:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  ```
- remove and restore the 2nd partition:

  ```
  gpt remove -i 2 disk0
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 372637568 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
  ```
- verify disk and partition:

  ```
  diskutil list
  diskutil verifyDisk disk0       
  diskutil verifyVolume disk0s2
  ```

---

Your Mac should be able to boot despite the MBR.

If you want (or have) to restore the pMBR because the MBR is stubborn/blocks the modification of the partition table do the following:

- get all disk details:

  ```
  diskutil list #below I assume the disk identifier of the internal disk is disk0
  gpt -r show disk0
  ```
- replace the GUID partition table:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  gpt destroy disk0
  gpt create -f disk0
  ```
- re-add all previous partitions visible in the last `gpt -r show disk0` output:

  ```
  gpt add -i 1 -b 40 -s 409600 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B disk0
  gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 372637568 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
  gpt add -i 3 -b 373047208 -s 262144 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
  gpt add -i 4 ...
  gpt add -i 5 ...
  ```

  If you get a *resource busy error* after one of the steps, just unmount disk0 again with

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
  ```
- Finally verify disk and partitions:

  ```
  diskutil list
  diskutil verifyDisk disk0       
  diskutil verifyVolume disk0s1
  diskutil verifyVolume disk0s2
  diskutil verifyVolume disk0s3
  #disk0s4 & disk0s5 can't be verified with the default macOS tools because the latter is a Linux swap and the former a Linux partition, probably with ext4
  ```

Comment: I cannot remove the disk0s2, as the command `gpt remove -i 2 disk0` throws an error: `gpt remove: disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0`. Similarly, the command `gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 372637568 -t 7C34[and so forth]` returns `gpt add: disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0` and `gpt add: disk0: error: no space available on device`. I have added new screen shots to my question for reference.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The second part of your answer fixed everything and my Mac booted as if nothing had happened!

Comment: @GintsK and klanomath : you two saved me 3 months of work. My deepest gratitude for documenting clearly this tricky issue.

Comment: `gpt add: disk0: error: no space available on device` is also caused by providing a wrong block number with `gpt add -b`. For more informations how **gpt** works please refere to this [man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/OSX/8/gpt/)

Comment: because my recovery partition was on the same disk as my broken partition, I was unable to unmount disk0, so I got a bootable usb stick with gparted on it, but really any linux distro would work - then used gdisk to change the partition type flag. Pretty sure the options are t to change type, then choose partition number, then search for type apfs and then w to write changes. It will warn about overwriting data but its just the table not the disk so it should be okay. I then rebooted holding option and my drive came up.

Comment: In your second step, remove and restore the 2nd partition: (`gpt remove -i 2 disk0`), does this delete all the data on that partition?

Comment: Also, does it matter if the drive is Filevault encrypted?