# APFS Container Corrupted - by using testDisk

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, apfs

I have a 1 TB drive on a late 2013 mbp.

This week it decided to stop booting  - was just hanging on the loading screen.

I have booted of an SD card and I *could* see the drive and browse it as read only.

I regretfully deployed testDisk - intending to look, but ended up saving the partition table.  I didn't make any changes intentionally to the disk layout, but since then it is messed up.

Turns out testDisk doesn't recognise APFS Containers and it has written it back incorrectly.

```
diskutil list /dev/disk0
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS 383B318C08526F8D75FF46  959.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS                         650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

```
sudo gpt -r show disk0
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640    14116056         
    14525696  1873432632      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1887958328    64297264         
  1952255592     1269536      3  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1953525128           7         
  1953525135          32         Sec GPT table
  1953525167           1         Sec GPT header
```

**UPDATE**: here is the same data from the 500GB HD that was cloned onto the 1TB drive - if seeing how it used to be is any help...

```
diskutil list /dev/disk4
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk5         499.9 GB   disk4s2
```

```
sudo gpt -r show disk4
Password:
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  976363488      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  976773128          7         
  976773135         32         Sec GPT table
  976773167          1         Sec GPT header
```

And disk 5 was the synthesized one in that Container...

```
/dev/disk5 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +499.9 GB   disk5
                                 Physical Store disk4s2
   1:                APFS Volume HD                      11.3 GB    disk5s1
   2:                APFS Volume HD - Data               231.6 GB   disk5s2
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 83.7 MB    disk5s3
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                530.6 MB   disk5s4
   5:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk5s5
```

Before the partition data was damaged, it has a `Container` and two disks `HD` and `HD - Data`.

Is there anything I can do to rebuild the partition table back to a healthy APFS Volume state?

Comment: With details like this, you’re in the correct spot for sure. We have several people with superb knowledge of this topic. If you have any snapshots from before or a backup, please add those details. We can assume none if you leave those out…

Comment: I have the old disk (500GB) that this OS was on before I cloned it to the 1TB if that helps.... Ill add it to the post

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [David Anderson](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/107222/david-anderson) for his previous detailed posts [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340097/apfs-partition-inaccessible-container-missing) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338063/failed-attempt-to-fix-macos-partition-startup-volume-set-to-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-f) I managed to work it out and restore the partitions.  You are a legend!

For anyone else who has this issue - this is what I did:

First remove the 2 incorrect partitions

```
sudo gpt remove -i 2 /dev/disk0
sudo gpt remove -i 3 /dev/disk0
```

And then add back in the new APFS partition

```
sudo gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 1953115488 -t apfs /dev/disk0
```

The *KEY* part here is working out the correct Size - in my case - 1953115488.

David explains how to find the correct values in this post [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338063/failed-attempt-to-fix-macos-partition-startup-volume-set-to-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-f).

But I also found it by accident.

I initially created the new partition with the incorrect size.

I assumed I wanted a 1TB partition, split over blocks of 512k - so `1000000000000 / 512 = 1953125000`

After creating the partition at that size, it didn't work, so I ran a `verifyVolume` on the APFS Container

```
diskutil verifyVolume  disk0s2
```

And that failed with

```
warning: nx_block_count is 244139436, while device block count is 234379555
```

so - the block count was `244139436`.

Using Davids' calculations each APFS block is 8 Logical blocks, so I multipied the `nx_block_count` by 8 to get the correct size of `1953115488` for the APFS Container.