# Lost my APFS partition after using EaseUS partition manager on Bootcamp

Tags: mac, bootcamp, partition, startup, apfs

I used macOS mojave(APFS partition) and Windows10(Bootcamp). And I tried to expand Bootcamp partition with moving Windows OEM partition by EaseUS partition master in windows.
After this, I can’t find APFS partition installed macOS.

I use MacBook Pro 2016.

I think “disk0s2” was APFS partition, but now it is “Windows Recovery” partition.

Do you have any ideas to solve this?
(I am Japanese, so I'm sorry for my poor English)

I tried “gpt show” and “diskutil list” on macOS Recovery
[image: I tried “got show” and “diskutil list” on macOS Recovery]

**Additional information**
I tried the commands `dd if=/dev/disk0s2 count=1 bs=512 | vis -c` in a Terminal app of macOS Utility from network boot, and the terminal says,

```
-bash-3.2# dd if=/dev/disk0s2 count=1 bs=512 | vis -c
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes transferred in 0.005472 secs (93568 bytes/sec)
)us??-ҵ?\^A\0\0\0\0\0\0\0?\M^F\^Z\0\0\0\0\0\^A\0\0\M^@\0\0\0\0NXSB\0\^P\0\0?\M^B?\^B\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\^B\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"\^R???\M^_@}\M^Bvy57
?(h?8\0\0\0\0\0?\M^F\^Z\0\0\0\0\0\^X\^A\0\0 l\0\0?\M^J\0\0\0\0\0\0\^R\r\0\0\0\0\0\0\a\0\0\0004*\0\0\^E\0\0\0\^B\0\0\0\^S*\0\0!\0\0\0\M^Qr8\0\0\0\0\0\M^U?\b\0\0\0\0\0\^A\^D\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0d\0\0\0\^C\^D\0\0\0\0\0\0\M^T\M^N\^A\0\0\0\0\0\M^V\M^N\^A\0\0\0\0\0?0\^B\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0-bash-3.2#
```

.

Comment: can you boot to Windows?

Comment: @DavidAnderson,   Yes!

Comment: Open `compmgmt.msc` on Windows, go to "Disk Management" (under "Storage"), locate the very big "Windows Recovery" partition. Does it say "NTFS (healthy)" or RAW or something ? !!!DO NOT FORMAT THE DRIVE!!!

Comment: I hesitate to post an answer to this question because your Mac appears to have been using Core Storage in some sort of Fusion Drive arrangement, but `diskutil list` only shows one drive.

Comment: @user2531336 Yes, Disk manager said it is RAW...

Comment: Excellent news, chances are high your data is there, YAY!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Windows, you can open a Command Prompt window as an Administrator. Next, you could enter the commands given below to change `disk0s2` to an APFS type.

```
diskpart
select disk 0
select partition 2
set id=7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC override
gpt attributes=0x0000000000000000
exit
```

## Update

The output from `dd if=/dev/disk0s2 count=1 bs=512 | vis -c` contains the character sequence `NXSB` which gives evidence that `disk0s2` is a APFS container. The sequence that follows `NXSB` is `\0\^P\0\0?\M^B?\^B\0\0\0\0\`. This sequence indicates the size value of `49283834` in the GPT is wrong for the 2nd entry (`disk0s2`). This incorrect value would cause the APFS volume to remain unmounted. Unfortunately, because the sequence contains question mark (`?`) characters, the correct value for the size can not be precisely determined.

Based on this new information, I can only guess at a solution. Below is my best guess.

Enter the following commands while booted to macOS Internet Recovery.

```
diskutil unmountdisk /dev/disk0
gpt remove -i 2 /dev/disk0
diskutil unmountdisk /dev/disk0
gpt remove -i 3 /dev/disk0
diskutil unmountdisk /dev/disk0
gpt add -i 2 -b 76806 -s 49316602 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
```

### How to determine the exact size for `disk0s2`.

1. While booted to macOS Internet Recovery, copy the first 512 bytes of `disk0s2` to a flash drive. Below is an example, where the flash drive volume label is `MYFLASHDRV`. You will need a flash drive that is `MS-DOS (FAT)` or `ExFAT` formatted.

   ```
   dd if=/dev/disk0s2 count=1 bs=512 of=/Volumes/MYFLASHDRV/hexdump.bin
   ```
2. Print out a hex dump of the saved file. Post the output to your question.

   Upload the `hexdump.bin` file to the website [File to hexadecimal converter](https://tomeko.net/online_tools/file_to_hex.php?lang=en).

   > Note: Before uploading the file, make sure the box labeled "Use 0x and comma as separator (C-like)" is unchecked and the box labeled "Insert newlines after each 16B" is checked off.

   **Or**, find another Mac and run the command shown below.

   ```
   hexdump -Cv /Volumes/MYFLASHDRV/hexdump.bin
   ```

   **Or**, boot to Windows, then download and run the command shown below. Here, I assume the flash drive is assigned the drive letter `D:`.

   ```
   writehex < D:\hexdump.bin
   ```

   > Note: You will need to download the `readgpt1.1.0x64.zip` file from the [readgpt website](https://sourceforge.net/projects/readgpt/). You can extract the `writehex.exe` application from this zip file. *This is a website that I created*.
3. Determine the size in 4096 bytes sectors of the APFS container partition (`disk0s2`). I can do this for you and update my answer. Or, you can read the accepted answer to the question: [Tried to fix filesystem type: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF and probably made it worse](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/353315/tried-to-fix-filesystem-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff-and-probably).

### Alternative method to determine the exact size for `disk0s2`.

1. While booted to macOS Internet Recovery, enter the commands given below.

   ```
   export LC_CTYPE="ASCII"
   dd if=/dev/disk0s2 bs=1 count=16 skip=32 2>/dev/null | vis -wc; echo
   ```

   If value of `49316602` posted in my above guess is correct, then you should get the following output.

   ```
   NXSB\0\^P\0\0\M-z\M^B\M-p\^B\0\0\0\0
   ```

   If your results are different, then you can post your results and wait for me to update my answer. **OR**, you can proceed to step 2.
2. Find another Mac and enter the command shown below. Here you need to replace the string with your results.

   > Note: It is important that the string be enclosed by single quotes ('). Do not use double quotes (").

   ```
   echo -n 'NXSB\0\^P\0\0\M-z\M^B\M-p\^B\0\0\0\0' | unvis | hexdump -Cv
   ```

   The above command would produce the following output.

   ```
   00000000  4e 58 53 42 00 10 00 00  fa 82 f0 02 00 00 00 00  |NXSB............|
   00000010
   ```
3. Determine the size in 4096 bytes sectors of the APFS container partition (`disk0s2`). The procedure for doing this is posted in the accepted answer to the question: [Tried to fix filesystem type: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF and probably made it worse](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/353315/tried-to-fix-filesystem-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff-and-probably).

Comment: Funny enough, that was exactly what gonna be what I would have answered provided op confirmed it was NOT formatted in NTFS as ... if it is, he will want `testdisk` to revocer data.

Comment: Thank you so much. And I tried this method(because I didn’t format disk0).  It seems that I succeed in changing to an APFS type.  However, I can’t still open macOS(when I start my MacBook, I used “option” key to select OS, but only I can see is windows).  And disk0s3 is still “raw”.  disk0s3 may be macOS’s partition...

Comment: My answer was based on your statement that partition was a APFS container. However, as I posted in my comment to your question, I did not think you were right. Trying my answer did not damage your drive because no new volumes mounted.

Comment: @DavidAnderson. Thank you very much.  I don’t know Core Storage and APFS well, so could you tell me the statement of my drive?

Comment: Don't worry, the above commands are non-destructive, somehow, your partition has an incorrect ID but the data is still there ... so, you go ahead and do that and see if it works (as-in you can mount the partition again in macos).

Comment: I tried that but my Macbook doesn’t recognize the partition which is installed macOS...

Comment: @MasanobuAricawa: I updated my answer. I would advise you post the hex dump.

Comment: @DavidAnderson: Thank you very much for helping me.  I tried the method, `diskutil unmountdisk /dev/disk0
gpt remove -i 2 /dev/disk0
diskutil unmountdisk /dev/disk0
gpt remove -i 3 /dev/disk0
diskutil unmountdisk /dev/disk0
gpt add -i 2 -b 76806 -s 49316602 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0`, and now I can mount my macOS partition!  Thank you so much!

Comment: @DavidAnderson thank you very much! you saved my life! your solution fixed my problem which was basically the same. Thanks man! you roll!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Easeus and solved it using gdisk.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/
I donated $25 because it saved me from doing something stupid.

Overview  ( Print out [A gdisk Walkthrough by Rod Smith](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/walkthrough.html) )

Download the windows version and unzip.
Command Prompt - must Run as Administrator ( or create Command Prompt shortcut and change Advanced Properties to Run as Administrator )

`cd` to `gdisk` folder

`gdisk64 0:` ( this opens root level, there is a gdisk32.exe also)

`Command (? for help): p`  ( this lists partition numbers, my mac was 2 )

`Command (? for help): i`  ( information on partition number )
`Partition number (1-3): 2` ( in my case the APFS was now Windows RE )

`Command (? for help): l` ( list/search partition codes af0a is the code for Apple APFS)

`Command (? for help): t`  ( t changes the partition code )
`Partition number (1-3): 2`
`Current type is 2700 (Windows RE)`
`Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 2700): af0a`
`Changed type of partition to 'Apple APFS'`

`Command (? for help): w`
`Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING`
`PARTITIONS!!`
`Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y`

Here is the command prompt text:

```
C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Downloads\@ GDISK>gdisk64 0:

GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p

Disk 0:: 61279344 sectors, 233.8 GiB
Sector size (logical): 4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 91BA5126-A853-4FDF-85C5-A15CB06EE24D
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 5
First usable sector is 6, last usable sector is 61279338
Partitions will be aligned on 2-sector boundaries
Total free space is 129 sectors (516.0 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1               6           76805   300.0 MiB   EF00
   2           76806        39139305   149.0 GiB   2700  Ma
   3        39139312        61279215   84.5 GiB    0700

Command (? for help): i
Partition number (1-3): 2

Partition GUID code: DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC (Windows RE)
Partition unique GUID: AE6B38B0-D322-4A09-B871-0F92B87082CA
First sector: 76806 (at 300.0 MiB)
Last sector: 39139305 (at 149.3 GiB)
Partition size: 39062500 sectors (149.0 GiB)
Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
Partition name: 'Ma'

Command (? for help): l

Type search string, or <Enter> to show all codes: apfs
af0a Apple APFS

Command (? for help): t
Partition number (1-3): 2

Current type is 2700 (Windows RE)
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 2700): af0a
Changed type of partition to 'Apple APFS'

Command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to \\.\physicaldrive0.
Disk synchronization succeeded! The computer should now use the new
partition table.
The operation has completed successfully.
```

Comment: Among other recipes I've chosen this one to fix my partitions problem. I've used EASUS partition manager from bootcamp windows installed on macbookpro. The single operation I did was resize of the bootcamp partition. After this operation my other APFS partitions got GUID type changed to DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC (sic). I've revealed this with the 'gpt - show disk0' command from a MacOS recovery terminal, that I run from a USB MacOS installer. Windows was the only bootable OS left on my ssd.
gdisk app helped me to fix the GPT data.
I've used EaseUS Partition version 16.0.0, Free ed