# My APFS won't boot, please help

Tags: hard-drive, windows, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

This is a follow-up question for  [Lost my APFS partition after using EaseUS partition manager on Bootcamp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360158/lost-my-apfs-partition-after-using-easeus-partition-manager-on-bootcamp)

I did the same thing - used EaseUS to reformat a windows drive to be larger, and made my APFS unbootable. I followed the instructions:

> From Windows, you can open a Command Prompt window as an Administrator. Next, you could enter the commands given below to change disk0s2 to an APFS type.
>
> ```
> diskpart
> select disk 0
> select partition 2
> set id=7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC override
> gpt attributes=0x0000000000000000
> exit
> ```

Which recovered my APFS drive perfectly. I also had a partition (number 3 on disk 0) and it was an OS X Journaled Extended drive (Which I think is HFS+). Frantically, I ran the same script above changing that drive to APFS, which is still unusable.

I'm so clueless and trying to scour the internet to figure out how to change the drive back to HFS+ so it can be accessed again.

Comment: @davidanderson Might be one for you :-)

Comment: The id for "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" is `48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`. Does that help?

Comment: I hope you found a fix for the issue you had.
I found that Apple APFS partition GUID type is 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC. I had issue with GUID replacement by a EASUS Partition manager from bootcamp windows on macbook. I had only Windows as bootable OS. Fixed my issue with the gdisk app. The EaseUS Partition version 16.0.0, Free ed. was the faulty app that broke GPT scheme.