# MacOS missing after using EaseUS partition on Bootcamp

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, partition

I used EaseUS partition on bootcamp in order to resize the storage on my Windows OS. After succesfully resizing it, the mac OS is missing. Whenever I restart my Macbook Air and hold alt(option) button, it only shows windows.

I tried the diskutil list and gpt disk show and here's what I found:
[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

[image]

[image]

Comment: UPDATE: After Doing some research and attempting to fix my problem. Now I cannot boot into windows OS. I believe I entered wrong commands that unmounted my windows partition.

Comment: The output you posted shows a Windows Recovery partition type (`DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC`) where normally a Apple type partition would be found. If you are using Mojave or newer then this should be an APFS partition type (`7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`). What version of macOS and Windows are you using? Did you use the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows? What is the model year of your MacBook Air? Have the images you posted changed after the research in your UPDATE comment?

Comment: The macOS version was Catalina (I updated it from Yosemite) and I installed windows 10 using bootcamp. The model of my macbook air is A1466 so I'm guessing it's a 2015 model. After I tried to fix it, I noticed that disk0s3, the bootcamp partition, is missing. I think I stupidly unmounted it.

Comment: I voted to close this question, because the OP has posted any answer stating basically this a duplicate of the question: [Lost my APFS partition after using EaseUS partition manager on Bootcamp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360158/lost-my-apfs-partition-after-using-easeus-partition-manager-on-bootcamp)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I finally found a fix for this problem from a previous a question answered by David Anderson.

[Lost my APFS partition after using EaseUS partition manager on Bootcamp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360158/lost-my-apfs-partition-after-using-easeus-partition-manager-on-bootcamp)