# Can't find APFS partition on external SSD after trying to merge partitions on Windows with EaseUS

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, apfs

Someone else had a similar problem and seemed to be able to fix it in the Ask Different post "[Lost my APFS partition after using EaseUS partition manager on Bootcamp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360158/lost-my-apfs-partition-after-using-easeus-partition-manager-on-bootcamp)" but the answers are confusing to me. I'm not super tech savvy and don't usually mess around with my hard drive partitions.

I had a 5TB external SSD partitioned in half, one half for my Mac backups (APFS) and the other half (NTFS) for my PC backups. I needed more space for my PC backups, so I split my Mac APFS partition in half using Disk Utility. This left me with a 1.3TB APFS partition, a 2.5TB NTFS partition, and an unallocated 1.3TB partition (I think I formatted it as ExFAT).

I tried to merge the new unallocated 1.3TB with my other 2.5TB of PC backups. I used EaseUS partition manager for this. I tried to be very careful to not touch the 1.3TB APFS partition while using EaseUS.

I don't know what happened, but my PC backup partition is still 2.5TB and my APFS partitions don't show up on my Mac when I mount the drive. I'm pretty sure my APFS partition is the 1.3TB one titled "Windows Recovery" , `disk2s2`, and the 1.3TB of free space I wanted to add to the 2.5TB partition is still there.

Please, help me fix my drives! I am scared to do anything at the moment for fear of losing my files. I'm using a 2019 MacBook Pro running Monterey.

---

Here's what comes up when I type `diskutil list`:

```
Tylers-MBP:~ Tyler$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         250.7 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.7 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     181.3 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 300.0 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.1 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      3.2 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            23.4 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 23.4 GB    disk1s5s1

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *5.0 TB     disk2
   1:       Microsoft Basic Data ⁨PC backup⁩               2.5 TB     disk2s1
   2:           Windows Recovery ⁨⁩                        1.3 TB     disk2s2
                    (free space)                         1.3 TB     -
```

---

Using a data recovery app, it can see my files (some at least, it hasn't finished scanning yet) in the APFS partition I want to access and shows the names of the volumes. So I don't think they've been overwritten, but I don't know how to access them. Here are the results of a few commands I've seen asked for in other threads:

Running `sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk2s2 count=1 bs=512 | vis -c` I get this:

```
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes transferred in 0.547588 secs (935 bytes/sec)
Q'?)\^W? ?\^A\0\0\0\0\0\0\0?\M^^\0\0\0\0\0\0\^A\0\0\M^@\0\0\0\0NXSB\0\^P\0\0\^X 2\^R\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\^B\0\0\0\0\0\0\0?~(?*?EU?F?+$l9\M^W?G\^B\0\0\0\0\0\M^^\M^^\0\0\0\0\0\0\^X\^A\0\0pl\0\0?%\^B\0\0\0\0\0e?\^A\0\0\0\0\0F\0\0\0?\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0?G\^B\0\0\0\0\0\^W4\^X\0\0\0\0\0\^A\^D\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0d\0\0\0CI\^A\0\0\0\0\0\r\^D\0\0\0\0\0\0A?\^A\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0,?\^A\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0%
```

and running `sudo diskutil verifyVolume /dev/disk1s2` I get this:

```
Verifying file system
Volume could not be unmounted
Using live mode
Performing fsck_apfs -n -l -x /dev/rdisk1s2
Checking the container superblock
Checking the checkpoint with transaction ID 3456817
Checking the EFI jumpstart record
Checking the space manager
Checking the space manager free queue trees
Checking the object map
Checking the encryption key structures
Checking volume /dev/rdisk1s2
Checking the APFS volume superblock
The volume Preboot was formatted by newfs_apfs (748.77.4) and last modified by apfs_kext (1934.141.2)
Checking the object map
Checking the snapshot metadata tree
Checking the snapshot metadata
Checking the fsroot tree
Checking the extent ref tree
Verifying volume object map space
Verifying allocated space
The volume /dev/rdisk1s2 appears to be OK
File system check exit code is 0
Restoring the original state found as mounted
Finished file system verification on disk1s2 (Preboot)
```

and when I type `sudo hexdump -Cv -n 512 /dev/disk2s2` I get this:

```
00000010  c1 9e 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 80 00 00 00 00  |?...............|
00000020  4e 58 53 42 00 10 00 00  18 20 32 12 00 00 00 00  |NXSB..... 2.....|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  b7 7e 28 d5 2a b9 45 55  |........?~(?*?EU|
00000050  a1 46 cb 2b 24 6c 39 97  ea 47 02 00 00 00 00 00  |?F?+$l9.?G......|
00000060  c2 9e 00 00 00 00 00 00  18 01 00 00 70 6c 00 00  |?...........pl..|
00000070  d5 25 02 00 00 00 00 00  65 b9 01 00 00 00 00 00  |?%......e?......|
00000080  46 00 00 00 cc 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |F...?...........|
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  e3 47 02 00 00 00 00 00  |........?G......|
000000a0  17 34 18 00 00 00 00 00  01 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.4..............|
000000b0  00 00 00 00 64 00 00 00  43 49 01 00 00 00 00 00  |....d...CI......|
000000c0  0d 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  41 a1 01 00 00 00 00 00  |........A?......|
000000d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  2c c8 01 00 00 00 00 00  |........,?......|
000000e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000100  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000130  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000140  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000160  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000190  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000200
```

Any idea what to do?

Additionally, one of my volumes was encrypted with a password. When I tried entering it in iBoysoft, it said the password for that volume was incorrect, but I know it's not. Is that password protected volume inaccessible now?

Comment: When you say you partitioned the drive for Mac backups, then PC backups, was it in that order? If so, the order has been switched according to diskutil's output, which means whatever software you used put significant effort into moving partitions, or the data has been overwritten.

Comment: Yes, in that order. I don't think the PC partition went through though.

Comment: I’ve rolled back the edit that puts an answer in the question and linked to the Q&A that OP confirmed answered the question. Thanks for confirming the solution Ryan!