# MacBook filesystem FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF after deleting linux partition

Tags: macos, partition, recovery, apfs, dual-boot

So I have MacBook Air late 2015. I’ve been using bootcamp for a while.

Yesterday I installed rEFInd to use triple boot for Linux. Made partition for Linux. Later I decided to delete this partition and extended Macintosh HD. Later when I restarted MacBook it was not able to boot.

I used Internet Recovery and found some threads about this issue:

- [Tried to fix filesystem type: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF and probably made it worse](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/353315/tried-to-fix-filesystem-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff-and-probably?rq=1)

I tried:

```
diskutil umountDisk disk0    
gpt remove -i 2 disk0
```

And when I try to:

```
gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 322344416 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
```

it says not enough space or something like that. I got stuck in here.

[image]

---

I fixed my problem by this commands!!

```
gpt remove -i 3 disk0
gpt remove -i 2 disk0
gpt destroy /dev/disk0
gpt create -f /dev/disk0 
gpt add -b 40 -s 409600 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B /dev/disk0
gpt add -b 409640 -s 322344416 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
gpt add -b 361738240 -s 128495616 -t EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 /dev/disk0
```

After this commands I was able to boot in macOS, no data loss or anything but unfortunately 20 gb is missing from Macintosh HD which was Linux partition at first. After booting to macOS I tried to `sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0` but it didn’t work. Also Windows Bootcamp is not working properly: when I boot in Windows 10 it says Error code 0xc000000e.