# MacBook Pro stuck on GRUB minimal Bash at startup

Tags: macos, terminal, startup, bash, unix

I had a dual boot Linux Mint 19 and macOS on my MacBookPro11,2. Since the CPU was overheating with Linux, I decided today to delete the Linux partition.
Little problem, when I start my MacBook Pro now, I just have this menu on startup:

> "GNU Grub version 2.02 - Minimal BASH-Like line editing is supported
>   grub>"

If I type `ls`, this is what I get:

> (hd0) (hd1) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1).

What could I do to boot into macOS?

Output from `diskutil list disk0`.

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF               228.8 GB   disk0s2
```

Comment: You may also want to ask a question about how to remove Grub from your EFI partition.

Comment: Hi thefruitismine, did you end up finding a solution on this?
I'm stuck on the same issue. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just try type `exit` on the GNU GRUB.

It fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This gives a new result at least! (“StartImage failed: Load Error”)

Answer (score 1):

### Use Startup Manager

When you use Startup Manager to select a startup disk, your Mac starts up from that disk once, then returns to using the disk selected in [Startup Disk preferences](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202796#startupdisk).

1. Press and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key immediately after turning on or restarting your Mac.
2. Release the Option key when you see the Startup Manager window.

   > If your Mac is protected by a [firmware password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455), you can release the key when you're asked to enter the password.
3. Select your startup disk, then click the arrow under its icon, or press Return.

   > If you press and hold the <kbd>control</kbd> key during this step, your selection is saved in Startup Disk preferences, so it persists until you change it.

[image]

If your Mac is using OS X Lion 10.7.3 or later, you can also use this method to start up from your [Time Machine backup disk](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250). Startup Manager identifies your Time Machine backup as ”EFI Boot.”

**References**
The above answer was copied from *"How to select a different startup disk"*, https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202796, January 29, 2019.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, when I hold the "Alt" key during startup, I only have one choice for the startup : "EFI Boot". After selecting it, I only have the grub> command line.

Comment: I suppose you will need to post the output from `diskutil list disk0` for this computer. You can do this if booted to [Recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314). An alternative would be to post the output from `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` from a live version of Linux. Also, add to your question the model year of your Mac and the version of OS X (macOS) that is installed.

Comment: Here is the result of the diskutil command :/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF               228.8 GB     disk0s2



The model is : « MacBookPro11,2" (I bought it in 2015)


Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: OS X 10.10.5 (14F27)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 14.5.0

Answer (score -2):

It seams that remove linux partition broken your MacOS partition with a wrong type FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF, you can try to restore MacOS partition with proper type in recovery mode terminal.

I fix this issue with this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/307787/246241

Comment: You should flag the question as a duplicate if all you are doing is saying that another answer answers the question