# iMac retrieve old linux partition after dual boot removal

Tags: imac, partition, unix, space

On my iMac I installed a dual boot with Linux Mint.
However, I realized that the videos were freezing some times, so I deleted the Linux partition.
Now, the Mac is working normally, but instead of having a partition of 1 TB, I just have a 800GB's total space on my Hard Disk.

How can I do to retrieve the 200GB of space that were on the Linux partition I deleted?

Below is the output from `diskutil list`.

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER 
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            800.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF               1.0 MB     disk0s4
```

Comment: Post the results from the Terminal application command `diskutil list` to your question.

Comment: Here is the result of the command "diskutil list" :

/dev/disk0 #: TYPE NAME SIZE IDENTIFIER 0: GUID_partition_scheme *1.0 TB disk0 1: EFI EFI 209.7 MB disk0s1 2: Apple_HFS Macintosh HD 800.0 GB disk0s2 3: Apple_HFS Recovery HD 650.0 MB disk0s3 4: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF 1.0 MB disk0s4

Comment: Why do you say in this question: "the Mac is working normally", but in the [other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359755/macbook-pro-stuck-on-grub-minimal-bash-at-startup) you say "MacBook Pro stuck on GRUB minimal Bash at startup"?

Comment: Actually, I have 2 Mac computers : a 27 inch iMac, which is working normally (except I don't know how to retrieve my 200GB partition) : it's the one concerned by this question. My second computer is a MacBook Pro, which can't boot : it's stuck on the grub command line. For this second computer, another topic has been created.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the commands below should work.

```
sudo diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s4
sudo diskutil resizevolume disk0s2 R
```

Comment: I launched both commands, but the Mac OS partition hasn't resized to 1TB : $ 
$ diskutil resizevolume disk0s2 R
Finished partitioning on disk0s2 Macintosh HD
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            800.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

Comment: I launched these commands without sudo, and after rebooting my mac, it's refuses to start : it makes a loop with the startup sound and I can't access to anything (the screen blinkes every 2 seconds as it restarts)