# MacOS partition formatted FFFFFFF etc after bootcamp install

Tags: disk-utility, partition, data-recovery, internet-recovery

My macOS partition has been changed to FFFFFFF format as seen in the attached images.

There’s a similar question regarding this topic, however I would like to preserve the data on the partition in question. This is the question I’m talking about [macOS partition startup Volume type FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307780/macos-partition-startup-volume-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff#).

Here is what I’m given with the

```
diskutil list
```

command:

[image: ][1]]
[image]

Once again, if anyone can help me with preserving the data from the partition while fixing it, I’d be incredibly grateful

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What caused the partition to change its partition type? I revised the linked answer and it seems to preserve the data, why do you think it won't? Have you checked https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282550/data-not-backed-up-partition-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff?

Comment: Because the linked answer suggests to remove the partition and then reformat it. From my own research it seems that if I remove a partition it will wipe my data. I didn’t want to test it on my own and have my data wiped. Thanks for your help!

Comment: To be clear, I haven’t checked if the specific command wipes the partition as I couldn’t find that info. I could only find that removing a partition will delete its data. Sorry if I come off as extremely novice, however that’s what I am. Cheers again

Comment: I also believe that my installation of bootcamp was what caused the partition to change its format. I had installed windows 10, it was working fine, as was macOS. Then windows bluescreened and I ended up having to reinstall windows. This was when my macOS partition changed it’s partition type.

Comment: Thanks your coming back to me. Yes, wiping the partition is destructive, but it doesn't wipe the data, only the metadata. The trick is to create a partition that exactly matches the one you've deleted, so that the metadata is recreated correctly. That's what the linked question is all about. I would recommend that you test the procedure with an external drive first (format it, create a file, wipe it, check it is unreadable, format it again and check if the file is there), if that works, you can be confident that it'll work with your macOS partition.

Comment: I’ve tried to remove and re add all partitions, however now the volumes won’t verify, nor will they mount. I’ll add photos of my issue and updated diskutil list in the post

Comment: Did you follow all steps in the linked answer exactly? I've noticed that partition 3 is missing in your second screenshot. You may want to go through all steps again, I hope it will work.

Comment: I tried adding all three partitions a number of times, in the last screenshot I didn’t add the final partition as it was the bootcamp partition So I thought it shouldn’t matter. I have since added it and the volumes will still not verify. I’m not sure what to do from here