# Catalina partition turns into type FFFFFFF/unbootable and unmountable "disk0s2" after Mavericks install

Tags: disk-utility, partition, data-recovery

I'm having a similar issue with this ([MacOS partition formatted FFFFFFF etc after bootcamp install](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399020/macos-partition-formatted-fffffff-etc-after-bootcamp-install?newreg=3c73c8b3582b45bc8ad4f79a105b1e23)), but I got confused while reading the comments.

I thought it would be a great idea to dualboot Catalina and Mavericks on my laptop, and I already had a Bootcamp-ed Windows 10 partition that was unused, so I wiped that, installed Mavericks, all went fine until it restarted and my Catalina partition didn't show up in the boot picker.

I assumed it was just simply because Mavericks has no idea what APFS is - it just showed up in Disk Utility as "disk0s2". I created a Catalina installer, booted into its disk utility and it doesn't even show up, until you go to the partition menu.

As I said earlier, I got lost unfortunately with all of the guides. Any help is greatly appreciated, especially for keeping the data in disk0s2 intact.

This is what `gpt -rf show disk0` gives me:
[image]

It's this classic FFFFFFFFF partition type again.

Comment: If you want to know the exact commands to enter, then boot to the Catalina installer and enter the command `gpt -rf show disk0`. Post the output to your question. This command will not change your Mac. The command just prints out the GUID partition table (GPT).

Comment: It's unbelievable how macOS keeps resetting people's partition type codes like this as if it were malware. I've had to fix this exact issue three times in the last day just from doing APFS resize operations in Mojave's disk utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot to the Catalina installer and enter the commands shown below.

> Note: The values `409640` and `349609376` were taken from the output posted in the question.

```
gpt -f remove -i 2 disk0
gpt -f add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 349609376 -t apfs disk0
```

Comment: that worked! surprisingly quite simple, honestly