# bootcamp NO BOOTABLE DEVICE after gpt add EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 disk0

Tags: bootcamp, partition, startup

My macbook has three os at the same time: macOS, bootcamp win10, ubuntu.
When booting, I choose os through rEFInd.
After I removed ubuntu, I found that only windows and efi boot were left when booting.
After entering the efi boot, the screen is grub.
In order to restore macOS, I referred to the following methods:
[macOS partition startup Volume type FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307780/macos-partition-startup-volume-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff/307787#307787)

After macOS was repaired, I found that win10 could not be accessed.
the error is "NO BOOTABLE DEVICE - INSERT BOOT DISK AND PRESS ANY KEY"
I guess it may be modified when adjusting disk type.
gpt add -i 3 -b 244551680 -s 245682176 -t EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 disk0

Can anyone help?
thanks a lot.

macOS: 10.15.7 Catalina
MacBook Pro 2013

```
sh-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         85.0 GB    disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                125.8 GB   disk0s3
sh-3.2# fdisk /dev/disk0
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 30515/255/63 [490234752 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 255  63 - 1023 255  63 [         1 -  490234751] <Unknown ID>
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
sh-3.2# gpt -vv -r show /dev/disk0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: mediasize=251000193024; sectorsize=512; blocks=490234752
gpt show: /dev/disk0: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Sec GPT at sector 490234751
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  166018024      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  166427664   78124016         
  244551680  245682176      3  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  490233856        863         
  490234719         32         Sec GPT table
  490234751          1         Sec GPT header
sh-3.2# dd if=/dev/rdisk0s3 count=1 2>/dev/null | hexdump -C
00000000  eb 52 90 4e 54 46 53 20  20 20 20 00 02 08 00 00  |.R.NTFS    .....|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 90 93 0e  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 80 00 80 00  f3 69 92 0e 00 00 00 00  |.........i......|
00000030  04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ff 4c ea 00 00 00 00 00  |.........L......|
00000040  f6 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  f7 9f 46 02 12 ee f5 34  |..........F....4|
00000050  00 00 00 00 fa 33 c0 8e  d0 bc 00 7c fb 68 c0 07  |.....3.....|.h..|
00000060  1f 1e 68 66 00 cb 88 16  0e 00 66 81 3e 03 00 4e  |..hf......f.>..N|
00000070  54 46 53 75 15 b4 41 bb  aa 55 cd 13 72 0c 81 fb  |TFSu..A..U..r...|
00000080  55 aa 75 06 f7 c1 01 00  75 03 e9 dd 00 1e 83 ec  |U.u.....u.......|
00000090  18 68 1a 00 b4 48 8a 16  0e 00 8b f4 16 1f cd 13  |.h...H..........|
000000a0  9f 83 c4 18 9e 58 1f 72  e1 3b 06 0b 00 75 db a3  |.....X.r.;...u..|
000000b0  0f 00 c1 2e 0f 00 04 1e  5a 33 db b9 00 20 2b c8  |........Z3... +.|
000000c0  66 ff 06 11 00 03 16 0f  00 8e c2 ff 06 16 00 e8  |f...............|
000000d0  4b 00 2b c8 77 ef b8 00  bb cd 1a 66 23 c0 75 2d  |K.+.w......f#.u-|
000000e0  66 81 fb 54 43 50 41 75  24 81 f9 02 01 72 1e 16  |f..TCPAu$....r..|
000000f0  68 07 bb 16 68 52 11 16  68 09 00 66 53 66 53 66  |h...hR..h..fSfSf|
00000100  55 16 16 16 68 b8 01 66  61 0e 07 cd 1a 33 c0 bf  |U...h..fa....3..|
00000110  0a 13 b9 f6 0c fc f3 aa  e9 fe 01 90 90 66 60 1e  |.............f`.|
00000120  06 66 a1 11 00 66 03 06  1c 00 1e 66 68 00 00 00  |.f...f.....fh...|
00000130  00 66 50 06 53 68 01 00  68 10 00 b4 42 8a 16 0e  |.fP.Sh..h...B...|
00000140  00 16 1f 8b f4 cd 13 66  59 5b 5a 66 59 66 59 1f  |.......fY[ZfYfY.|
00000150  0f 82 16 00 66 ff 06 11  00 03 16 0f 00 8e c2 ff  |....f...........|
00000160  0e 16 00 75 bc 07 1f 66  61 c3 a1 f6 01 e8 09 00  |...u...fa.......|
00000170  a1 fa 01 e8 03 00 f4 eb  fd 8b f0 ac 3c 00 74 09  |............<.t.|
00000180  b4 0e bb 07 00 cd 10 eb  f2 c3 0d 0a 41 20 64 69  |............A di|
00000190  73 6b 20 72 65 61 64 20  65 72 72 6f 72 20 6f 63  |sk read error oc|
000001a0  63 75 72 72 65 64 00 0d  0a 42 4f 4f 54 4d 47 52  |curred...BOOTMGR|
000001b0  20 69 73 20 63 6f 6d 70  72 65 73 73 65 64 00 0d  | is compressed..|
000001c0  0a 50 72 65 73 73 20 43  74 72 6c 2b 41 6c 74 2b  |.Press Ctrl+Alt+|
000001d0  44 65 6c 20 74 6f 20 72  65 73 74 61 72 74 0d 0a  |Del to restart..|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 8a 01  a7 01 bf 01 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200
sh-3.2# pwd
/Volumes/BOOTCAMP/Boot
sh-3.2# ls -lgt BCD*
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 wheel  32768 11 17 23:50 BCD
prwxr-xr-x@ 1 wheel      0  9 30  2022 BCD.LOG1
prwxr-xr-x@ 1 wheel      0  9 30  2022 BCD.LOG2
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 wheel  32768  9 30  2022 BCD.LOG
```

ubuntu 40G is deleted and not asigned

Comment: What does the output from the command `ls /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/boot/bcd`?

Comment: @DavidAnderson output as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following command while booted to macOS Recovery.

```
fdisk -e /dev/disk0
```

The command is interactive. You should input the following.

```
edit 1
ee
n
1
244551679
edit 2
7
n
244551680
245682176
flag 2
quit
y
```

---

### Update

If you see the following display when booting Windows, then you should rebuild the `BCD` file.

[image]

The steps to rebuild the `BCD` file are given below.

1. Use the Boot Camp Assistant to create a Windows 10 install disk. This should be a flash drive. Do **not** remove the existing Windows 10 installation.

   [image]
2. Boot from the flash drive and proceed until you reach the following display. (You need to reach this point in order for the Windows drivers to automatically load.)

   [image]
3. Press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open a Command Prompt window.
4. Enter the following commands. When `bootrec` prompts for input, enter `a`.

   ```
   attrib -h -s c:\boot\bcd
   del c:\boot\bcd
   bootrec /rebuildbcd
   attrib +h +s c:\boot\bcd
   exit
   ```
5. Restart the Mac and boot Windows from the internal drive.

---

### References

- [Use Bootrec.exe in the Windows RE to troubleshoot startup issues](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-bootrec-exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues-902ebb04-daa3-4f90-579f-0fbf51f7dd5d)

Comment: I finished entering these commands. Now there is a blue screen. title is Recovery and error code is "0xc000000e". Is this the right step? Any suggestions for next steps? thanks a lot.

Comment: Despite your best efforts, there was not enough information given in your question to post an exact compete answer. The procedure, in the [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307780/macos-partition-startup-volume-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff/307787#307787) you linked to, destroyed the information I usually use to fix your type of problem. Based on your comment, you should proceed using my updated answer.