# How do I remove Ubuntu from my MacBook?

Tags: disk-utility, partition, unix

My MacBook has three OSs at the same time: macOS, Boot Camp Windows 10, and Ubuntu. It will display Windows, Macintosh HD, and EFI Boot (going to Ubuntu) when pressing the option when booting. I split the disk size as follows:

macOS: 85 GB
Windows: 120 GB
Ubuntu: 40 GB
total: 256 GB

- I used Disk Utility when trying to remove Ubuntu. However, I could not remove the partition Ubuntu uses. Then, macOS is broken (only Windows is fine). I solved macOS by following methods: [macOS partition startup Volume type FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307780/macos-partition-startup-volume-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff/307787#307787).
- Then, Windows is broken (only macOS is fine). I solved Windows by following methods: [bootcamp NO BOOTABLE DEVICE after gpt add EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 disk0](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466561/bootcamp-no-bootable-device-after-gpt-add-ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7-d).
- Now Windows and macOS are fine. I hope that EFI Boot will not be displayed when pressing the option when booting and Ubuntu 40 GB comes back to macOS (ie, macOS: 125 GB, Windows: 120 GB). What should I do without destroying other OSs while removing Ubuntu?

```
sh-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         85.0 GB    disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                125.8 GB   disk0s3 
sh-3.2# gpt -vv -r show /dev/disk0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: mediasize=251000193024; sectorsize=512; blocks=490234752
gpt show: /dev/disk0: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Sec GPT at sector 490234751
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  166018024      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  166427664   78124016         
  244551680  245682176      3  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  490233856        863         
  490234719         32         Sec GPT table
  490234751          1         Sec GPT header
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Boot to macOS Catalina and enter the following commands.

   ```
   diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
   sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
   cd /Volumes/EFI/EFI
   rm -r BOOT
   rm -r ubuntu
   cd ~
   diskutil unmount disk0s1
   ```
2. Open a Command Prompt window by following steps 1 through 3 given as an update in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466561/bootcamp-no-bootable-device-after-gpt-add-ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7-d/466581#466581).
3. Enter the command given below.

   ```
   diskpart
   ```

   The command is interactive. You should input the following.

   ```
   select volume c:
   set id=7
   extend filesystem
   active
   exit
   ```
4. Rebuild the BCD by following steps 4 and 5 given as an update in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466561/bootcamp-no-bootable-device-after-gpt-add-ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7-d/466581#466581).

---

### Steps to Uninstall Ubuntu

These steps assume the Mac was setup the same as before you first uninstalled Ubuntu.

1. Boot to Windows.
2. Download the [GPT fdisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/) project from sourceforge.net. Extract the files to the default location.
3. Open a Command Prompt window as an administrator.
4. Enter the command given below. If the GPT fdisk version is not `1.0.9`, then make the appropriate substitutions.

   ```
   %userprofile%\gdisk-windows-1.0.9\gdisk64 0:
   ```

   This command is interactive. Enter the values given in the first column of the following table.

   | Entry | Type | Comment |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | `s` | command | Sort partitions |
   | `p` | command | Print the partition table |
   | `d` | command | Delete a partition |
   | `3` | parameter | Partition number |
   | `w` | command | Write table to disk and exit |
   | `y` | parameter | Confirm to proceed |
5. Boot to macOS Catalina and enter the following commands.

   ```
   diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
   sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
   cd /Volumes/EFI/EFI
   rm -r BOOT
   rm -r ubuntu
   cd ~
   diskutil unmount disk0s1
   ```
6. Boot to Windows.
7. Change the partition type for drive C: to 7. Two different ways to accomplish this are given below. The first way requires a full functioning Windows Recovery Environment (Windows RE). If your Windows RE is damaged or improperly configured, then choose the second way.

   - **The First Way:** Click `Start` > `Settings` > `Update & Security` > `Recovery` > under "Advanced startup", click `Restart now`.

     When the "Choose an option" menu appears, Click `Troubleshoot` > `Advanced options` > `Command Prompt`. If `Command Prompt` is missing, then your Windows RE is damaged or improperly configured. Sign in to get a Command Prompt window.

     Enter the command given below.

     ```
     diskpart
     ```

     The command is interactive. You should input the following.

     ```
     select volume c:
     set id=7
     exit
     ```

     Enter the command below to close the Command Prompt window.

     ```
     exit
     ```

     When the "Choose an option" menu appears, Click `Continue`.
   - **The Second Way:** Open a Command Prompt window as an administrator. Enter the command given below. If the GPT fdisk version is not `1.0.9`, then make the appropriate substitutions.

     ```
     %userprofile%\gdisk-windows-1.0.9\gdisk64 0:
     ```

     This command is interactive. Enter the values given in the first column of the following table.

     | Entry | Type | Comment |
     | --- | --- | --- |
     | `r` | command | Switch to recovery and transformations options menu |
     | `o` | command | Print protective MBR data |
     | `h` | command | Make hybrid MBR |
     | `2 3` | parameter | Partition numbers to be added to the hybrid MBR, in sequence |
     | `y` | parameter | Place EFI GPT (0xEE) partition first in MBR (good for GRUB)? |
     | `ff` | parameter | MBR hex code for the second MBR partition |
     | `n` | parameter | Set the boot flag? |
     | `7` | parameter | MBR hex code for the third MBR partition |
     | `y` | parameter | Set the boot flag? |
     | `n` | parameter | Use remaining partition space to protect more partitions? |
     | `o` | command | Print protective MBR data |
     | `w` | command | Write table to disk and exit |
     | `y` | parameter | Confirm to proceed |

---

### References

- [Windows Recovery Environment (Windows RE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference?view=windows-10)

Comment: learned a lot, thank you very mush!

Comment: If I reinstall ubuntu, can I still use these command to remove it?