# Mac partition shows as type FFFF-FFF.... - partition doesn't show in boot menu

Tags: partition, diskutil

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 partition running on my Mac alongside the MAC OS. It started recently that I could only boot into a black screen in the Mac OS and now the partition in the boot menu has completely disappeared. Ubuntu still runs perfectly tho.
When I start via Internet recovery, in the results of `diskutil list` the mac partition has type FFFFFF-FFF...
The problem seems to be similar to [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238012/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffff-after-attempting-to-d#).
Could someone help me understand what I can do to fix my problem. I can't find any helpful information about the commands used in the linked solution to adapt them to my case. 
Or maybe there is a different approach to save the data on my mac partition?
Thanks a lot! :-)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Edit your question with output of `gpt -r show /dev/disk0` as in the question you linked to.  It would be good to indicate your macOS version and if your volume was formatted HFS or APFS.  If your macOS volume was HFS+ you can then follow the answer you linked to changing the partition start/end numbers in  `gpt  add  -i  2  -b  409640  -s  194016208  -t  hfs  /dev/disk0` to whatever `gpt -r show`gives you for partition 2.  If it was APFS you'd follow the answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/307787/115093) again updating the partition start and end points.

Comment: Thanks @lx07 for your answer :-) I will add the output of `gpt -r show /dev/disk0`  to my question shortly. I will have to start internet recovery again for that...   Regarding the formatting of the volume I am not 100% sure. I think I had hfs+. What happens if I use the wrong one? Is there still a way of finding out? Also about my macOS version I am not sure... My guess is High Sierra.

Comment: You can either tell us the internal drive type (if SSD and 10.13 or newer, then probably APFS (the missing recovery partition supports this assumption)) or use dd (`dd if=/dev/disk0s2 count=3 | vis -c`)  to determine the proper partition type.

Comment: This answer should fit: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/305712/93229 - it explains all necessary methods to determine the former partition type (with hexdum & w/o hexdump (macOS Recovery/Recovery Mode).

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I had to wait for my ubuntu backup to finish... Your answers helped me a lot but I could not complete the process. The verification of the volume in the end failed (see picture)

Comment: I tried to boot in Mac OS and it boots into a black screen :-/ What could I try next? Is there now a way to save my data from recovery mode via the terminal?

Comment: @HaLed It's unclear what's wrong here. Restore a backup. If you don't have a backup but happen to have a thumb drive or an empty external drive, install a full Mojave macOS (looks like a Mojave apfs layout) and TeamViewer there and invite me to a session. Please don't post ID & password of TeamViewer here but to klanomath(at)googlemail.com.

Comment: @klanomath wow this is an amazing offer!! I will do as you said and write you a mail once its done.. Only thing is that I am pretty sure it is not Mojave. Is there a way of finding out what I have at my state right now.. entering recovery mode for example?

Comment: @HaLed You can try to boot to disk20s3 and get the sys-vers there: in Utilities>Terminal you should be able to enter `sw_vers`. The disk is an SSD and it's either HS or Moj. Catalina has a slightly different volume layout: an additional "Macinotsh HD - Data" volume.