# Help I screwed up APFS Mojave partition FFFFFF error

Tags: bootcamp, mojave, partition, apfs

Apologies for the photo but I couldn't copy/paste because my mac is in recovery mode

[image]

Basically what I did was have Windows and Debian installed alongside encrypted OSX

but this morning I was desperate for space and the other operating systems were hardly used on this machine so I used the bootcamp tool to try and delete windows and regain the extra space.

The tool then gave an error but it looked liked windows had been removed so I went to the disk utility and  deleted any other partitions including the linux swap with the intent of merging them all manually.

I then rebooted the machine to find the question mark folder so I went into internet recovery mode but it looks like it can't detect the encrypted OSX partition and repair the bootloader

I am unsure what to do next as I need the files on this machine

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Install Mojave on external disk and see if it can see your real disk, unlock and repair (I suspect not). Since your disk is encrypted it is unlikely that a recovery tool (e.g. DiskDrill) or commercial recovery service could work.  Maybe better to just erase disk, reinstall and recover from Time Machine.

Comment: There are disk recovery tools (free & paid for) out there that might work .. I've had varied success & failure with Hard Disk Manager - there are 2 partition tables - one for OSX and one for Windows so you have to get them both correct.

Comment: This type of question has be asked many times. See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=FFFFFFFF). Basically, you need to replace `FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF` with `7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`.

Comment: Since you fixed your Mac, I will vote to close as a duplicate question of  [macOS partition startup Volume and Recovery Disk type FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF plus part of the disk corrupted?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384503/macos-partition-startup-volume-and-recovery-disk-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ff). This is not an exact match, but rather the closest I could find.