# Can't boot, OS volume type 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFF'

Tags: disk-utility, partition, startup, recovery

after trying to remove a linux distribution through diskutil, i somehow managed to mess up my OS-Volume - i can't boot:

- Output of `diskutil list`

[image: output diskutil list]

- Output of `gpt -r show /dev/disk0`

[image: output gpt -r show /dev/disk0]

Thats the output i get after trying this fix: [related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238012/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffff-after-attempting-to-d#), before it looked like this:

[image: before fix]

In the recovery-mode disk tool, the disk0s2 is now shown but grayed out, i cannot mount it either. Trying `diskutil verifydisk disk0` gives me the following error:

[image: verify error]

Thanks for the help

Comment: You will have to go through the process of identifying what the partition type should be. This [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff/305712#305712) explains how to do this. Do you know what version of macOS was installed?

Comment: I have mojave installed. So i guess it needs to be APFS instead of HFSJ Extended. However, when i use `gpt remove -i 2 disk0` again, i now get: `gpt remove: unable to open device 'disk0': Resource busy
`

Comment: @pmoritz You have to boot to Internet Recovery Mode or to a second boot drive (e.g. a thumb drive)!

Comment: Try entering `diskutil unmountdisk disk0` before the `gpt` command.

Comment: Problem was that I wasn't using internet recovery. It works now, thanks